# Select all contents of textbox when it receives focus (Vanilla JS or jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

What is a Vanilla JS or jQuery solution that will select all of the contents of a textbox when the textbox receives focus?

Comment: See [_"Selecting text on focus using jQuery not working in Safari and Chrome"_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5044224/601179) as well.

Comment: @gdoron for some reason that link redirects to this question itself.

Comment: @Destrictor, Yes, it should have been this: ["Selecting text on focus using jQuery not working in Safari and Chrome"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269722/selecting-text-on-focus-using-jquery-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome)

Comment: The problem with most of these solutions is that they do not work correctly when changing the cursor position within the input field. Take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20826207/641452

Answer (score 393, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:text").focus(function() { $(this).select(); } );
});
```

Comment: Also just for extra info:
"input[type=text]" now can be "input:text"
regards

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me on Chrome and the jQuery website says it is browser dependent. Can anyone else verify?

Comment: It looks like WebKit browsers interfere with this because of the mouseup event. I added this and it worked: $('input:text').mouseup(function(e) {
  return false;
 });

Comment: Kenny is correct, but unfortunately 'mouseup' also affects Chrome spinner controls. Triggering off 'click' rather than 'focus' seems to solve that

Comment: I use like this:
$("input:text").select().focus();

Comment: @RichardKennard, but wouldn't a spinner have `type="number"` not `type="text"`? One downside of the `mouseup` approach is in comment to Zach's answer (by enigment): "once the cursor is in the field, clicking somewhere within the selected text to position the cursor there doesn't work; clicks are effectively disabled."

Comment: `$("input:text").focus().select();` seems to work. Is there a reason it's not this simple?

Comment: As @Kenny's comment webkit dose indeed interfere. I ended up using this: `$("input:text").on('mouseup', function() {
            $(this).select();
        });`
Works fine in the latest IE, chrome and firefox browsers.

Comment: Using `this.select()` is faster. [It's vanilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select).

Comment: `focus` seems to be working in webkit now, at least in my tests. The issue with `mouseup` is that it doesn't work if the user tabs into the input. It also prevents the user from moving the caret with the mouse.

Answer (score 282):

```html
<input type="text" onfocus="this.select();" onmouseup="return false;" value="test" />
```

Comment: + onmouseup="return false" to stop deselect on click

Comment: +1 for some kind of stopEvent for mouseup, or this doesn't work reliably. The downside of doing that is that once the cursor is in the field, clicking somewhere within the selected text to position the cursor there doesn't work; clicks are effectively disabled. Still, for situations where selecting the whole text on focus is desirable, it's probably the lesser of two evils.

Comment: I was able to somewhat get around the issue raised by enigment by setting a global variable doMouseUp to false, during the onMouseDown event, if this != document.activeElement. Then, during onMouseUp, reset doMouseUp to true and return the doMouseUp value before you reset it. This is getting convoluted and needs code - I'll post an answer explaining it better.

Comment: While separating script from markup, this is the most elegant way to auto-select `onfocus` for a single text field. If I were going to have more than one field where I wanted this auto-select functionality, I would create a script function and call it.

Comment: I don't get it. What's the difference between having `onmouseup="return false;"` and not having it?

Comment: **Do NOT** add `onmouseup="return false;"` if you want the user to be able to freely select and edit the text _after_ focusing inside the textbox. With this code, the text will be locked into a "select all" situation and the user will not be able to edit it unless the user types in a new text or uses arrow keys to move around. Honestly this feels like a very weird behavior and wouldn't make sense unless the textbox is intended to be permanently non-editable (and therefore disabled).

Comment: Technically, you don't need `onmouseup="return false;"` if you simply want the selection to occur when the user _first_ clicks or tabs. And +1 for the vanilla javascript!

Comment: return false; breaks spinner controls for numeric inputs. The up/down arrows will spin forever. Instead I called select() after a setTimeout

Answer (score 47):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type=text]").focus().select();
});
```

Comment: Confirmed.  The current highest voted / accepted answer doesn't seem to work for Chrome.

Answer (score 39):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:text")
        .focus(function () { $(this).select(); } )
        .mouseup(function (e) {e.preventDefault(); });
});
```

Comment: This is good. Thanks! 

The comment by enigment to Zach's answer gives one downside of preventing default of the `mouseup` event: "once the cursor is in the field, clicking somewhere within the selected text to position the cursor there doesn't work; clicks are effectively disabled. Still, for situations where selecting the whole text on focus is desirable, it's probably the lesser of two evils."

Answer (score 29):

jQuery is not JavaScript which is more easy to use in some cases.

Look at this example:

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" onclick="this.focus();this.select()">Text is here</textarea>
```

Source: [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/auto-select-textarea-text/), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select)

Comment: Maybe that's OK if you don't mind getting your markup and code all mixed up; most people try to keep their script 'unobtrusive' nowadays. Oh... and jQuery *is* Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of onclick, works great. Not everyone uses jQuery so glad to see another option.

Comment: this assumes users only use the mouse

Comment: can use onfocus="this.focus();this.select()" for keyboard

Answer (score 23):

This is not just a Chrome/Safari issue, I experienced a quite similar behavior with Firefox 18.0.1. The funny part is that this does not happen on MSIE! The problem here is the first **mouseup** event that forces to unselect the input content, so just ignore the first occurence.

```
$(':text').focus(function(){
    $(this).one('mouseup', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    }).select();
});
```

The timeOut approach causes a strange behavior, and blocking every mouseup event you can not remove the selection clicking again on the input element.

Comment: +1 for the usage of one to prevent a single mouseup. I really disliked not being able to select text with the mouse after the initial click.

Answer (score 23):

**HTML :**

```js
document.getElementById("text-filled").addEventListener("focus", function() { this.select(); });
```

```html
Enter Your Text : <input type="text" id="text-filled" value="test with filled text">
```

**Using JQuery :**

```
$("#text-filled").focus(function() { $(this).select(); } );
```

**Using React JS :**

In the respective component -

```
<input
  type="text"
  value="test"
  onFocus={e => e.target.select()}
/>
```

Comment: This works for me in React: `onFocus={(e) => e.target.select()}`

Answer (score 11):

my solution is to use a timeout. Seems to work ok

```
$('input[type=text]').focus(function() {
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        _this.select();
    }, 10);
});
```

Comment: This is the solution I use and prefer. I use a timeout value of 0 since that will cause it to be added to the end of the current event queue, which means it will run after the "mouseup" event.

Answer (score 6):

This will also work on iOS:

```
<input type="text" onclick="this.focus(); this.setSelectionRange(0, 9999);" />
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select

Answer (score 4):

I know inline code is bad style, but I didn't want to put this into a .js file.
Works without jQuery!

```
<input type="text" value="blah blah" onfocus="this.select(); this.selAll=1;" onmouseup="if(this.selAll==0) return true; this.selAll=0; return false;"></input>
```

Answer (score 3):

The answers here helped me up to a point, but I had a problem on HTML5 Number input fields when clicking the up/down buttons in Chrome.

If you click one of the buttons, and left the mouse over the button the number would keep changing as if you were holding the mouse button because the mouseup was being thrown away.

I solved this by removing the mouseup handler as soon as it had been triggered as below:

```
    $("input:number").focus(function () {
        var $elem = $(this);
        $elem.select().mouseup(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $elem.unbind(e.type);
        });
    });
```

Hope this helps people in the future...

Comment: Nopes. u are giving a solution to a self-generated problem. If you look properly at the answer, they are binding `mouseup` to the **text** input fields only and not `number`s. This problem should not come therefore

Comment: The problem with binding mouseup is that it interferes when moving the cursor within the field.  This is a better solution, but if you tab into the field, then the next mousedown will be lost (and user will not be able to move the cursor with the mouse).  That is better than losing all mousedowns!

Answer (score 3):

This will work, Try this -

```
<input id="textField1" onfocus="this.select()" onmouseup="return false" />
```

Works in Safari/IE 9 and Chrome, I did not get a chance to test in Firefox though.

Answer (score 3):

Like @Travis and @Mari, I wanted to autoselect when the user clicked in, which means preventing the default behaviour of a `mouseup` event, but not prevent the user from clicking around. The solution I came up with, which works in IE11, Chrome 45, Opera 32 and Firefox 29 (these are the browsers I currently have installed), is based on the sequence of events involved in a mouse click.

When you click on a text input that does not have focus, you get these events (among others):

- `mousedown`: In response to your click. Default handling raises `focus` if necessary and sets selection start.
- `focus`: As part of the default handling of `mousedown`.
- `mouseup`: The completion of your click, whose default handling will set the selection end.

When you click on a text input that already has focus, the `focus` event is skipped. As @Travis and @Mari both astutely noticed, the default handling of `mouseup` needs to be prevented only if the `focus` event occurs. However, as there is no "`focus` didn't happen" event, we need to infer this, which we can do within the `mousedown` handler.

@Mari's solution requires that jQuery be imported, which I want to avoid. @Travis's solution does this by inspecting `document.activeElement`. I don't know why exactly his solution doesn't work across browsers, but there is another way to track whether the text input has focus: simply follow its `focus` and `blur` events.

Here is the code that works for me:

```
  function MakeTextBoxAutoSelect(input)
  {
    var blockMouseUp = false;
    var inputFocused = false;

    input.onfocus =
      function ()
      {
        try
        {
          input.selectionStart = 0;
          input.selectionEnd = input.value.length;
        }
        catch (error)
        {
          input.select();
        }

        inputFocused = true;
      };

    input.onblur =
      function ()
      {
        inputFocused = false;
      };

    input.onmousedown =
      function ()
      {
        blockMouseUp = !inputFocused;
      };

    input.onmouseup =
      function ()
      {
        if (blockMouseUp)
          return false;
      };
  }
```

I hope this is of help to someone. :-)

Comment: +1 Thanks, but how can this be re-written so that you don't hard-code the 'txtCustomer' control into the script? Is there a way to pass down a 'this' object?

Comment: One way would be to create a utility function to apply the behaviour to any element, passed in as a parameter. Within that function, the element reference would be hard-coded -- to the parameter. You could then call it on any number of input elements, identified by whatever means you have at your disposal. :-)

Comment: Sorry I am a noob. Could you please update your answer with an example? Thanks

Comment: Just wrap the code I wrote in a function declaration that takes a parameter called "txtCustomer". I recommend renaming "txtCustomer" to something else, but if you're not confident in doing that, it will technically work with the variable named "txtCustomer". That is to say: function MakeTextBoxAutoSelect(txtCustomer) { **what I wrote above** }

Answer (score 3):

I know there are already a lot of answers here - but this one is missing so far; a solution which also works with ajax generated content:

```
$(function (){
    $(document).on("focus", "input:text", function() { 
        $(this).select(); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to slightly improve Zach's answer by incorporating a few function calls. The problem with that answer is that it disables onMouseUp completely, thereby preventing you from clicking around in the textbox once it has focus.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" onfocus="this.select()" onMouseUp="javascript:TextBoxMouseUp();" onMouseDown="javascript:TextBoxMouseDown();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var doMouseUp = true;
    function TextBoxMouseDown() {
        doMouseUp = this == document.activeElement;
        return doMouseUp;
    }
    function TextBoxMouseUp() {
        if (doMouseUp)
        { return true; }
        else {
            doMouseUp = true;
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is a slight improvement over Zach's answer. It works perfectly in IE, doesn't work at all in Chrome, and works with alternating success in FireFox (literally every other time). If someone has an idea of how to make it work reliably in FF or Chrome, please share.

Anyway, I figured I'd share what I could to make this a little nicer.

Comment: There is an error in your code - the second method should be called "TextBoxMouseUp".  Take a look at my answer which uses a similar approach.

Comment: It should be noted that `onMouseUp=""` and `onMouseDown=""` are not the correct w3 standard. They should be `onmouseup=""` and `onmousedown=""`. As with other html attributes, they should are written in lowercase not in camel case.

Answer (score 2):

> *What is a JavaScript or jQuery solution that will **select** all of the contents of a textbox when the textbox receives **focus**?*

You only need to add the following attribute:

```html
onfocus="this.select()"
```

For example:

```html
<input type="text" value="sometext" onfocus="this.select()">
```

*(Honestly I have no clue why you would need anything else.)*

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').focus(function () {
    var self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        self.select();
    }, 1);        
});
```

Edit: Per @DavidG's request, I can't provide details because I'm not sure why this works, but I believe it has something to do with the focus event propagating up or down or whatever it does and the input element getting the notification it's received focus. Setting the timeout gives the element a moment to realize it's done so.

Comment: Please explain your answer rather than just pasting in some code.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (posting since it is not in answers but in a comment)

```
 $("#textBox").focus().select();
```

Answer (score 1):

**The best and very simple solution:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:text").focus().select();
});
```

Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="this.focus();this.select()"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you chain the events together I believe it eliminates the need to use `.one` as suggested elsewhere in this thread.

Example:

```
$('input.your_element').focus( function () {
    $(this).select().mouseup( function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: If you are programming in ASP.NET, you can run the script using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript in C#:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(txtField, txtField.GetType(), txtField.AccessKey, "$('#MainContent_txtField').focus(function() { $(this).select(); });", true );
```

Or just type the script in the HTML page suggested in the other answers.

Comment: The question doesn't have ASP.NET anywhere. :|

Comment: True, I posted this just in case the programmer is using ASP.NET. It can be helpful for someone looking for an answer using the framework (as this helped me). I'm just sharing and hopefully someone will find it helpful.

Comment: Just in case the programmer is using ASP.NET, he will add 'asp.net' tag to the question. :|

Answer (score 0):

I sow this one some where , work perfectly !

```
            $('input').on('focus', function (e) {
                $(this)
                $(element).one('mouseup', function () {
                        $(this).select();
                        return false;
                    })                        .select();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of late to the party, but this works perfectly in IE11, Chrome, Firefox, without messing up mouseup (and without JQuery).

```
inputElement.addEventListener("focus", function (e) {
    var target = e.currentTarget;
    if (target) {
        target.select();
        target.addEventListener("mouseup", function _tempoMouseUp(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            target.removeEventListener("mouseup", _tempoMouseUp);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: yes but if you `focus` by tabbing into the field, you will find multiple mouseup event listeners attaching...

Answer (score 0):

I was using Zach's answer, but it breaks when using type="number" with up/down spinner controls, since the return false; causes the spinner to spin forever when clicked. So instead I call select() after a setTimeout to allow the mouseup to propagate first. I don't like the answers which are setting a timeout directly in the focus event listener, because they are gambling on whether select will occur after mouseup.

```
function selectOnFocus(input: any) {
  $(input).on('focus', function (e) {  
    $(this).one('mouseup', function (e) {
      setTimeout(() => { $(this).trigger('select'); }, 0);
    })
      .trigger('select');
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution is next:

```
var mouseUp;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(inputSelector).focus(function() {
        this.select();
    }) 
    .mousedown(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":focus")) {
          mouseUp = true;
        }
        else {
          mouseUp = false;
        }
     })
     .mouseup(function () {
        return mouseUp;
     });
});
```

So mouseup will work usually, but will not make unselect after getting focus by input