# jQuery masked input plugin. select all content when textbox receives focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

This is a followup question to this question:

[select all contents of textbox when it receives focus (Javascript or jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480735/select-all-contents-of-textbox-when-it-receives-focus-javascript-or-jquery)

Basically I am using a textbox in conjunction with the [jQuery masked input plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/maskedinput/)(Edit: Link may no longer point at relevant version)

When the masked input textbox receives focus I want to select all of the contents of that textbox, but it seems as though having this plugin binded to the textbox prevents that. I was just wondering if there was a way around this.

Below is a sample .html page that demonstrates the issue:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="masktest" type="text" value="01/01/2009" />
    <br />
    <input id="focustest" type="text" value="on focus will select all contents..." />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-joshbush.googlecode.com/files/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.1.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#masktest").mask("99/99/9999");

            // Contents of textboxes will be selected when receiving focus.
            $("input[type=text]")
                .focus(function() {
                    $(this).select();
                });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm the author of the [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) for jQuery.  I decided that this should be the default behavior for completed masks and I got it into the latest release.  You can read the details [here](http://digitalbush.com/2009/03/10/masked-input-plugin-122/)

Comment: Does your plugin support money masking ? like $3,439.44

Answer (score 3):

Hey Jon, not too sure about the performance of this, but this should work:

```
    $(function() {


        // Contents of textboxes will be selected when receiving focus.
        $("input[type=text]")
            .focus(function() {
                var mask = "99/99/9999";
                $(this).unmask(mask).select().mask(mask);
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

its working for me in FF3.

```
$("input[type=text]").focus(function(e) {
  var that = this;
  setTimeout(function(){$(that).select();},10);
  return false;
});
```

setTimeout will "queue" the select() execution, I was wondering about:
- Ok mask functions do your work THEN I'll select the content. That THEN is where the queue is useful.

Just an idea. I hope it works as expected.

Comment: it works (in IE7 as well)! also very handy to know, I can see this potentially being useful in other similar instances that may occur.

Comment: I couldnt get this solution to work with setTimeout... but by doing $("body").animate({opacity:1.0}, 10, function(){$(that).select();}); it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

> Problem

Defaut value is deleting when focus

> Resolve : added little patch code to mask.js file (jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.min.js)

```
(function(a){var c=(a.browser.msie?"paste":"input")+".mask";var b=(window.orientation!=undefined);a.mask={definitions:{"9":"[0-9]",a:"[A-Za-z]","*":"[A-Za-z0-9]"}};a.fn.extend({caret:function(e,f){if(this.length==0){return}if(typeof e=="number"){f=(typeof f=="number")?f:e;return this.each(function(){if(this.setSelectionRange){this.focus();this.setSelectionRange(e,f)}else{if(this.createTextRange){var g=this.createTextRange();g.collapse(true);g.moveEnd("character",f);g.moveStart("character",e);g.select()}}})}else{if(this[0].setSelectionRange){e=this[0].selectionStart;f=this[0].selectionEnd}else{if(document.selection&&document.selection.createRange){var d=document.selection.createRange();e=0-d.duplicate().moveStart("character",-100000);f=e+d.text.length}}return{begin:e,end:f}}},unmask:function(){return this.trigger("unmask")},mask:function(j,d){if(!j&&this.length>0){var f=a(this[0]);var g=f.data("tests");return a.map(f.data("buffer"),function(l,m){return g[m]?l:null}).join("")}d=a.extend({placeholder:"_",completed:null},d);var k=a.mask.definitions;var g=[];var e=j.length;var i=null;var h=j.length;a.each(j.split(""),function(m,l){if(l=="?"){h--;e=m}else{if(k[l]){g.push(new RegExp(k[l]));if(i==null){i=g.length-1}}else{g.push(null)}}});return this.each(function(){var ORJ=$(this).val();var r=a(this);var m=a.map(j.split(""),function(x,y){if(x!="?"){return k[x]?d.placeholder:x}});var n=false;var q=r.val();r.data("buffer",m).data("tests",g);function v(x){while(++x<=h&&!g[x]){}return x}function t(x){while(!g[x]&&--x>=0){}for(var y=x;y<h;y++){if(g[y]){m[y]=d.placeholder;var z=v(y);if(z<h&&g[y].test(m[z])){m[y]=m[z]}else{break}}}s();r.caret(Math.max(i,x))}function u(y){for(var A=y,z=d.placeholder;A<h;A++){if(g[A]){var B=v(A);var x=m[A];m[A]=z;if(B<h&&g[B].test(x)){z=x}else{break}}}}function l(y){var x=a(this).caret();var z=y.keyCode;n=(z<16||(z>16&&z<32)||(z>32&&z<41));if((x.begin-x.end)!=0&&(!n||z==8||z==46)){w(x.begin,x.end)}if(z==8||z==46||(b&&z==127)){t(x.begin+(z==46?0:-1));return false}else{if(z==27){r.val(q);r.caret(0,p());return false}}}function o(B){if(n){n=false;return(B.keyCode==8)?false:null}B=B||window.event;var C=B.charCode||B.keyCode||B.which;var z=a(this).caret();if(B.ctrlKey||B.altKey||B.metaKey){return true}else{if((C>=32&&C<=125)||C>186){var x=v(z.begin-1);if(x<h){var A=String.fromCharCode(C);if(g[x].test(A)){u(x);m[x]=A;s();var y=v(x);a(this).caret(y);if(d.completed&&y==h){d.completed.call(r)}}}}}return false}function w(x,y){for(var z=x;z<y&&z<h;z++){if(g[z]){m[z]=d.placeholder}}}function s(){return r.val(m.join("")).val()}function p(y){var z=r.val();var C=-1;for(var B=0,x=0;B<h;B++){if(g[B]){m[B]=d.placeholder;while(x++<z.length){var A=z.charAt(x-1);if(g[B].test(A)){m[B]=A;C=B;break}}if(x>z.length){break}}else{if(m[B]==z[x]&&B!=e){x++;C=B}}}if(!y&&C+1<e){r.val(ORJ);w(ORJ.length,h)}else{if(y||C+1>=e){s();if(!y){r.val(r.val().substring(0,C+1))}}}return(e?B:i)}if(!r.attr("readonly")){r.one("unmask",function(){r.unbind(".mask").removeData("buffer").removeData("tests")}).bind("focus.mask",function(){q=r.val();var x=p();s();setTimeout(function(){if(x==j.length){r.caret(0,x)}else{r.caret(x)}},0)}).bind("blur.mask",function(){p();if(r.val()!=q){r.change()}}).bind("keydown.mask",l).bind("keypress.mask",o).bind(c,function(){setTimeout(function(){r.caret(p(true))},0)})}p()})}})})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

if your 'completed' function doesn't work, try to replace this line:

`if (settings.completed && next == len)`

(this is line number 169 of noncompressed plugin) with that:

`if (settings.completed && eval(+next - 1) == len)`

While using this plugin with firebug, i've noticed, that 'next' variable jumps up over a symbol when last char of mask entered.
This way should work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution than timeout.

You can view jquery.maskedinput.js:293 there is a function for input focus and it is triggered only on inputs without "readonly" attribute so:

`$("input[type=text]").attr("readonly", true).select().removeAttr("readonly");`

...just like that. Works like a charm ;)