# How to perform .select() on jQuery masked text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, mask, masking

I'm using http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ plugin.

There is an input text with defined mask:

```
<input type="text" id="txtMyInput" class="FocusSense"/>
```

and a script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(function ($) {            
        $("#txtMyInput").mask("?9.99");            
    });
    $(".FocusSense").focus(function () {
        this.select();
    });
})
```

As you can see, I would like select all in `txtMyInput` on focus but but alas!
On focus, mask appears and lose `.select()`.

What should I do to preserve mask and `.select()`?

Comment: did you tried $(this).select(); ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are looking for, is this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(function ($) {            
        $("#txtMyInput").mask("?9.99");            
    });
    $(".FocusSense").focus(function (e) {
      var that = this;
      setTimeout(function(){$(that).select();},10);
      return false;
    });
});
```

setTimeout will "queue" the select() execution. So it will select the content after masking is completed.

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nYtDu/1/)

Answer (score 2):

you need to use $(this) to get the current object.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(function ($) {            
        $("#txtMyInput").mask("?9.99");            
    });
    $(".FocusSense").focus(function () {
        $(this).select(); // instead of this.select();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

sory change focus change click function;

```
jQuery(".FocusSense").click(function() {
    this.focus();
    this.select(); 
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

this.select() change jQuery(this).select();

```
$(".FocusSense").focus(function () {
    jQuery(this).select();
});
```

Comment: ohh sory .FocusSense focus select all text??

Answer (score -1):

This is duplicate of
'[jQuery masked input plugin. select all content when textbox receives focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480979/jquery-masked-input-plugin-select-all-content-when-textbox-receives-focus/23369361#23369361)' where I posted explanation for this fix.

**imeout method is unnecessary!**

```
$(".yourMaskedInput").attr("readonly", true).select().removeAttr("readonly");
```