# Convert to upper case while typing, with some delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I used following codes to convert to upper case while typing.

```
      $(".input_capital").live('keypress', function(e)
      {
        var defaultStr = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        var checkstr = $(this).val();
        var str1 = '';
        for (i = 0; i < checkstr.length; i++)
        {
            var ch = checkstr.charCodeAt(i);
             if (ch>=97 && ch<=122){
                str1 += defaultStr.charAt(ch-97);
             }else{
                str1 += checkstr.charAt(i);
              }
        }
        $(this).focus();
        $(this).val(str1);
     });
```

And the following code

```
  $(".input_capital").live('keypress', function(e)
  {
       $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
  });
```

all these above code is working fine. But for user able to view lower cases for some time. After that only its converting to upper case.

I tried with '`text-transform: uppercase`' in css. But it is not working in Samsung tab with Android Os. Please anybody help me to achieve this by script.

Comment: do you want transformation to be instant??

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you can try:

```
$(".input_capital").on('keydown', function(evt) {
  $(this).val(function (_, val) {
    return val + String.fromCharCode(evt.which).toUpperCase();
  });

  return false;
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5gLyX/

It has some flaws, but I think the idea is clear, and can be build upon.

---

**Better version**, though mind the `input` event which is not supported in IE<9.

```js
$('.input_capital').on('input', function(evt) {
  $(this).val(function(_, val) {
    return val.toUpperCase();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class='input_capital' rows='8'></textarea>
```

Comment: This is fine.One issue is there. I am unable to type at the middle. It will display the typed char only at the end.

Comment: and arrow key,back key and delete key also not working in chrome

Comment: @RamarajKaruppusamy That's to be expected. If you want to amend that, you'll have a lot of work (basically just for IE<9).

Comment: also, you can't press `delete` button.  It shows some char if you press the delete button

Answer (score 27):

`Note: This answer is without delay..if you like to avoid Jquery`

Try

```
<input type="text" style="text-transform: uppercase">
```

[Demo - JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oneofthelions/z45ygobL/)

Comment: l o l Damann!! Sometimes we want to show up how smart we are by using all jquery thing `lol` and look at this `lol` come and look at this `lol`

Comment: This only gives the _appearance_ that the text in in upper/lower case. If you send the value to the server, it will be in mixed case.

Comment: @DomenicD. yes I had trouble using this on submitting data to the server

Comment: Wow, very tricky way. I like it so much. BTW thanks bro.

Answer (score 5):

if you don't care ie<9 , listen the "input" event

```
$(".input_capital").bind("input", function(e){
   this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
});
```

and for IE<9, use "keyup" instead

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/MupXZ/6/

Comment: I am using jquery 5.1. So I cant use upper versions of jquery because of some plugin problem. Can u please suggest any other event than on.

Comment: @techfoobar Thinks op means `1.5.1`

Answer (score 2):

What about using keyup instead of keypress.

```
$(".input_capital").live('keyup', function(e)
  {
       $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
  });
```

So that the last letter is changed as soon as the key is released.

Like this : http://jsfiddle.net/mNVXK/

Comment: .live is no longer usable

Comment: But is was in 2012 :)

Answer (score 1):

Why you just not add this line

```
$(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
```

before `$(this).focus();`? And use `on()` instead of `live()`

Comment: I am using jquery 5.1. So I cant use upper versions of jquery because of some plugin problem. Can u please suggest any other event than on.

Answer (score 1):

To extend [@Yoshi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13155583/887539)

> #### This extension takes care of:
>
> **Backspace:** `8`
> **Tab:** `9`
> **Enter:** `13`
> **Arrow keys:** `37,38,39,40`

```
$(".input_capital").bind('keydown', function(event) {
    if ( $.inArray( event.keyCode, [8,9,13,37,38,39,40]) === -1 ) {
        $(this).val(function(i, val) {
            return val + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toUpperCase();
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Using `bind` cause [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13155261/887539) is using `jQuery 1.5.1`

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
$(".input_capital").live('keypress', function(e) {
    setInterval("$(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase())",100);      
});
```

Comment: It's better to use a function wrapped around that instead of a string, as well.

Answer (score 0):

for those using later versions of jquery replace live with on.
eg.

```
 $(".input_capital").live('keyup', function(e)  {
   $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

is now

```
$(".input_capital").on('keyup', function(e)  {
   $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

js

```
$('.input_capital').on('blur', function(evt) {
  $(this).val(function (_, val) {
    return val.toUpperCase();
  });
});
```

html

```
<input type="text" class="input_capital" style="text-transform: uppercase" />
```

Follow this: http://jsfiddle.net/5gLyX/389/