# force Uppercase using EditorFor Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Trying to force text in certain fields in a view that is adding records to the DB via Entity framework to uppercase.

Can I do it in the view EditorFor or can I do it in the controller to all fields easily before firing db.SaveChanges()?

Comment: Do it in the controller using `ToUpper()`, unless there's a need for the user to see it in uppercase?

Comment: Can I do that to all string fields when I do                                db.Travelers.Add(traveler);
db.SaveChanges(); or would I have to do each string field differently?

Comment: Using this approach you'd have to call `ToUpper` on each field. Alternatively you could create a custom Filter that acted on the incoming POST model.

Comment: Thanks Mark.....gonna do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the properties on your `ViewModel` server side using a helper method.

```
public T ViewModelToUpper<T>(T viewModel) where T : class
{
    foreach (var property in viewModel.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var value = property.GetValue(viewModel, null);
        if (value is string)
        {
            property.SetValue(viewModel, value.ToString().ToUpper());
        }
    }

    return viewModel;
}
```

Then you can call `viewModel = ClassName.ViewModelToUpper(viewModel)`. Now you don't have to worry about doing it for every `string` property as this will happen anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the UI with jQuery if you'd like. It's a little weird from a user perspective to be typing and have everything converted to uppercases (I'd check my caps lock). [Convert to uppercase as user types using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571514/convert-to-uppercase-as-user-types-using-javascript)

Your other option, better IMO, is to do this in the controller. You can use `ToUpper()`on the strings. Keep Globalization in mind.

Comment: The user is irrelevant at this point, it is being done in the db to adhear to a specific export format.

Comment: Can I do that to all string fields when I do db.Travelers.Add(traveler); db.SaveChanges(); or would I have to do each string field separately ? –

Comment: Well, you could do a partial class for the DB entity and put a method on it to do all the strings at once. Think: 'Travelers.Upper()' that goes through and does everything. Otherwise you'll do them individually.