# Select all text on focus using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a little jQuery function that is meant to automatically select text in an asp.net text box when it gets focus. However, the text in the text box gets selected, but immediately then deselects.

The code works if i bind to the focus event with .focus(function()) but I am adding the text boxes to the page dynamically which is why I think I need to use the live event.

Can anyone see a problem? The text boxes in question are in Item templates of two gridviews inside a multiview if that makes a difference?

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //Select all text in Cost Rate Text Boxes when they have focus
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".CostRateTextBox").live('focus', function () {
            $(this).select();
        });

    });

</script>
```

[image]

Edit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //Select all text in Cost Rate Text Boxes when they have focus
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".CostRateTextBox").live('focus', function () {
            $(this).select();
            preventDefault();
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: can we see rendered html for a small example?

Comment: Do you need to `preventDefault();`?

Comment: @Fourth - I have added an image as an example of the page.

Comment: @Lazarus - where to I need to add preventDefault()?

Comment: @WraithNath - anywhere within your 'focus' function. The answer below is similar, just replace the `return false;` with the `preventDefault();` as this covers a multitude of sins that `return false;` doesn't.

Comment: @WraithNath pass the focus event into the function and reference it before your `$(this).select();` call

Comment: @WraithNath sorry - meant to see some raw html to get a feel for what those text boxes look like from a markup perspective.

Comment: @Lazarus - I have added an edit to show the code with prevent default, although this is throwing an error saying the function is undefined. Would you mind amending my code to show where it should go?

Comment: @Dave - Thanks, would you mind posting an example of what you mean?

Comment: @Everyone - thanks all for your comments, I have got there in the end with the solution below. I have upvoted

Comment: @Lazarus: if you take a look at the jQuery docs for live, you'll see a [list of caveats](http://api.jquery.com/live/#caveats).  One of them is that `event.stopPropagation()` will not work and `return false;` must be used instead.

Comment: @Andy E - Thanks for that, I have to be honest, I don't use live() often.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery input select all on focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150275/jquery-input-select-all-on-focus)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It seems to be the `mouseup` event interfering. You'll notice if you click and hold in the form field then move outside of it to "`mouseup`" the selection sticks. Using `mouseup` instead of `focus` to trigger the `select()` method seems to work well:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //Select all text in Cost Rate Text Boxes when they have focus
    jQuery(function($){
        $("table.demo").on("mouseup", ".CostRateTextBox", function () {
            $(this).select();
        });
    });

</script>
```

### **Demo:** [jsfiddle.net/gableroux/jvJzX/12](http://jsfiddle.net/gableroux/jvJzX/12/)

See [original demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/jvJzX) for jQuery 1.3 - 1.8 compatible code.

Comment: Hi Marcel - Thanks, your solution worked, I was a little worried to begin with as this is a timesheet entry page and users would be using the tab key. Fortunately the tab behaviour already selects the text in the field so its only the click event I need to handle :)

Comment: @WraithNath: Exactly, `Tab` selects anyway so you don't need to trigger on focus.

Comment: just checked out your jsfiddle, very nice :)

Comment: @AndyE: Since there's so many rows and columns in his screenshot, it may just be easier to click a form field if it's in the opposite corner for example.

Comment: Updated demo so it works with latest jQuery, also tested on a textarea.
http://jsfiddle.net/gableroux/jvJzX/12/

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with a product search form I was working on. I know that this has already been answered, but I figured it can't hurt to submit my code, right?

```
$('#product-search').focus(function(){
    $('#product-search').mouseup(function(){
        $(this).select(function(){
            $(this).off('mouseup');
        });

        $(this).select();
    });
});
```

The advantage being that it only selects the text when the form first gets focus, rather than every time the form gets clicked, such as when a user wants to select a portion of the text.

I rewrote Marcel's fiddle to demonstrate the difference. http://jsfiddle.net/7tDYq/2/

Comment: You da MAN!  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Hmmm not exactly a good solution because you cannot select partial areas of the textbox for deletion or editing.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution I came up with in the question [jquery input select all on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24589806/1366033):

```js
$("input").focus(function(){
    $(this).on("click.a keyup.a", function(e){      
        $(this).off("click.a keyup.a").select();
    });
});
```

```js
$("input").focus(function(){
    $(this).on("mouseup.a keyup.a", function(e){      
        $(this).off("mouseup.a keyup.a").select();
    });
});

// event logger
$("input").on("mousedown focus mouseup click blur " + 
              "keydown keypress keyup change",
              function(e) {
     console.log(e.type);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="potato" />
<input type="text" value="tomato" />
```

### The Problem:

Here's a little bit of explanation:

First, let's take a look at the order of events when you mouse or tab into a field.
We can log all the relevant events like this:

```js
$("input").on("mousedown focus mouseup click blur keydown keypress keyup change",
              function(e) { console.log(e.type); });
```

[image: focus events]

Some browsers attempt to position the cursor during the `mouseup` event.  This makes sense since you might want to start the caret in one position and drag over to highlight some text.  It can't make a designation about the caret position until you have actually lifted the mouse. So functions that handle `focus` are fated to respond too early, leaving the browser to override your positioning.

But the rub is that we really do want to handle the focus event.  It lets us know the first time that someone has entered the field.  After that point, we don't want to continue to override user selection behavior.

### The Solution:

Instead, within the `focus` event handler, we can quickly attach listeners for the `click` (click in) and `keyup` (tab in) events that are about to fire.

> **Note**: The keyup of a tab event will actually [fire in the new input field, not the previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18020246/1366033)

We only want to fire the event once.  We could use `.one("click keyup)`, but this would [call the event handler once for each event type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24589084/1366033). Instead, as soon as either click or keyup is pressed we'll call our function.  The first thing we'll do, is remove the handlers for both.  That way it won't matter whether we tabbed or moused in.  The function should execute exactly once.

> **Note**: Most browsers naturally select all text during a tab event, but as [animatedgif pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22102081/1366033), we still want to handle the `keyup` event, otherwise the `click` event will still be lingering around anytime we've tabbed in. We listen to both so we can turn off the listeners as soon as we've processed the selection.

Now, we can call `select()` after the browser has made its selection so we're sure to override the default behavior.

Finally, for extra protection, we can add [**event namespaces**](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) to the `click` and `keyup` functions so the `.off()` method doesn't remove any other listeners that might be in play.

---

**Additionally**, if you want to extend jQuery with a [function called `once` that will fire exactly once for any number of events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24589200/1366033):

```js
//The handler is executed at most once per element for all event types.
$.fn.once = function (events, callback) {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).on(events, myCallback);
        function myCallback(e) {
            $(this).off(events, myCallback);
            callback.call(this, e);
        }
    });
};
```

Then you can simplify the code further like this:

```js
$("input").focus(function(){
    $(this).once("click keyup", function(e){      
        $(this).select();
    });
});
```

```js
//The handler is executed at most once per element for all event types.
$.fn.once = function (events, callback) {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).on(events, myCallback);
        function myCallback(e) {
            $(this).off(events, myCallback);
            callback.call(this, e);
        }
    });
};

$("input").focus(function(){
    $(this).once("click keyup", function(e){      
        $(this).select();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="potato" />
<input type="text" value="tomato" />
```

---

Tested in IE 10+, FF 28+, & Chrome 35+

Comment: This is a superior answer!

Comment: is there any reason why you can't just do ... $(sel).on('focus', function() { $(this).select(); }).mouseup(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });   ??

Comment: @NotoriousPet0, that's a pretty good solution ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/ccf7S/44/)).  The only thing I'd note is that after the first selection, you can't click and drag to select a portion of the text.  This isn't that big of a problem, but it's an odd UI experience.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  However, I'm in Chrome and some textareas and inputs don't have an issue with re-selecting text.  However, a couple of the inputs on my page using the exact same code are pushing the cursor to the end of whatever is in the box when you try to select text (and also not selecting the text).    I am wondering what the variable is in these certain cases, that is causing them to misbehave.   What browser are you seeing those issues in  ?  I'll go check the fiddle now.

Comment: Err sorry, had a new piece of code I was using ... will try to add to fiddle.