# Select Text on Focus of Input Element Generated by jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using the `jQuery UI` `AutoComplete` `Combobox` option as illustrated [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox).  This will start filtering the shown results immediately when you begin typing, but if an element is already selected, then typing (without manually removing the contents) will just append onto the string and typically not find anything.

I'd like the text to be selected by default whenever the input field receives focus, but am having trouble figuring out where to add that logic into the script.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/Fjj3J/) with this example on it.

Normally, to select the text in an input element when it recieves focus, you could execute the following, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124394/select-all-text-on-focus-using-jquery/6124595#6124595) SO question:

```js
//Select all text in Cost Rate Text Boxes when they have focus
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".CostRateTextBox").live('mouseup', function () {
        $(this).select();
    });
});
```

The `_createAutocomplete` function in the script is where the input box is created.  Is it possible to do this near the following line?

```js
this.input = $("<input>")
```

Comment: just use `$('input').focus()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the event handler when the input is created, like so ( and don't use live() ):

```
this.input = $("<input>")

          .appendTo(this.wrapper)
          .val(value)
          .attr("title", "")
          .addClass("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left")
          .autocomplete({
              delay: 0,
              minLength: 0,
              source: $.proxy(this, "_source")
          })
          .tooltip({
              tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
          }).on('mouseup', function() {
              $(this).select();
          });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/Fjj3J/1/)

And yes, you have to use `mouseup` to get the selection working.

Comment: `mousedown` works too, in my opinion works better since there is no delay from when you press down to when you release. May I ask why you suggested `mouseup` ? thanks : EDIT : OK, found it myself, mouseup works on IE, mousedown doesnt. :/

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your code:

```
 .tooltip({
            tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
  }).focus();
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/Fjj3J/1/)**

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when I mouse into the field, only when I tab into it.