# Using jquery .on when running a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following line of jquery which reacts to any key up event in any text input on a form. It then runs a function called `processPrimarySearch`:

```
$('#primarySearch input[type="text"]').on('keyup', this, processPrimarySearch);
```

This works, but I want to adapt it so `keyup` ignores a tab key press as described here: [Keyup event behavior on tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020098/keyup-event-behavior-on-tab)

I can't work out how to re-write this as I don't understand how to pass `this` before calling `processPrimarySearch`. For example I have the following but it doesn't work and I don't understand what I'm supposed to write to make it work:

```
$('#primarySearch input[type="text"]').on({

    "keyup": function(e) {
        if (e.which != 9) {
            // No reference to 'this'!
            processPrimarySearch();
        }
    }
});

function processPrimarySearch() {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is almost correct, you just need to use `call()` to provide the context for the function. Try this:

```
$('#primarySearch input[type="text"]').on({
  "keyup": function(e) {
    if (e.which != 9) {
      processPrimarySearch.call(this);
    }
  }
});

function processPrimarySearch() {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much. I wasn't aware of `.call()` so will look further into this.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Here's the docs for your reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call