# Select text on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select the text in a readonly input box, using jQuery, this is what I have:

```
    $('input').focus(function(){
        $(this).select();
    })
```

When I click on the input however, it quickly selects all the text, it "blinks", then it goes back to normal state of being unselected.

Any ideas around this?

Comment: This seems to work ok for me although it depends where I click. Clicking the end of the text content works fine, clicking the middle does the blink you describe the first time and then works the second time.

Comment: I tested the above code in jquery 1.4.3 and it works fine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the fact that the input box is readonly (*as you mention in you question*).
(*it is not a jQuery or javascript problem*)

IE, FF and Opera have no problem. But Chrome and Safari exhibit the issue you mention..

Looks like a different implementation, and i am not sure you can work-around that..

demo to showcase (*check in all browsers with console open*)
http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/N9qzq/3/

Comment: Thank you.. Will have to look at a different method, won't work in Chrome.

Answer (score 14):

I got it working using the below code . My chrome version:`Version 24.0.1312.52`

```
$("#inputid").on("focus",function(e){
    $(this).select();
});

$("#inputid").on("mouseup",function(e){
    return false;
});
```

Hope this helps ...

Comment: This is the cleanest solution, but you might want to use `e.preventDefault()` instead of `return false`.

Answer (score 5):

A combination of the two techniques worked for me, though my box wasn't read-only.  The normal select() works right away in Firefox.  However, in Safari, the mouseup and ordering of events causes it to deselect itself again on mouseup.  I attached a mouseup event that starts a select on a delayed timer after the mouseup should have finished interfering (if the text is still the default text to be replaced).

Example:

```
$('#your_selector').focus(function() {
  $(this).select();
}).mouseup(function() {
  if ($(this).val() === 'Enter search terms here'){
    var _self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){ _self.select()},30)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 <input onClick="this.select()" value="Blabla und Blublu" type="text" />
```

Should work

Comment: This functionality is the same as in the question - it'll have the same problem.

Comment: The event is different: click instead of focus. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150275/jquery-input-select-all-on-focus

Answer (score 2):

There's a little bit of an oddity happening here. `focus` happens on mousedown, but cursor placement happens on `click` (i.e. a `mousedown` followed by a `mouseup`). When the cursor is placed, any selection goes away.

So, you'll most likely want to keep your `focus` event (for tabbing and `trigger`ing purposes) but also add a `click` or a `mouseup` handler to do the actual select in the case of a click.

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function() {
    $(this).select();
}).click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === 'Your default value')
    {
        $(this).select();
    }
});
```

The `if` exists so that once a user has customized text in your input, they can click around without selecting text. Although, that doesn't really apply to a `readonly` text input, so it may be safely removed.

**Edit:**
Code seems to be inconsistent at best, so this may not be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what Gaby wrote in their post, this solution seems to be working for me:

```
$('input').focus(function(){
    var _self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){   console.log(_self.select())},100)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem testing on browsers.  Google has this problem, I think Opera too.  Firefox, IE ok.  I solved it by this.select() on both onclick and onfocus.

Answer (score -2):

Due to the inconsistency that people are mentioning, can you use CSS to simulate your selection? When the input receives the focus, apply CSS `color` and `background-color` so it looks like it's selected.

Comment: Absolutely not. The point is to make it convenient for the user to copy/paste the text in the field.