# How can I select inner content of inputbox when tabbing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-asp.net-mvc, inputbox, kendonumerictextbox

I have inputs which are text boxes. I want to have it so that when I tab to the input, the contents of the input become highlighted. How do I do that?

Right now, the content of the input is not highlighted when I tab. Just the cursor goes to the input box, but nothing is highlighted.

I am using Kendo UI for the input boxes for ASP.NET MVC 4 application.

Here's a sample input box I have:

```
<td id="ViewTextBox">@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor
    <double>(model => model.View).Format("#").Decimals(0).Min(0) .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "dPNumericbox" }) .Events(e => e .Change("BrowserSide.DP.ViewTextBoxChanged") ))
</td>
```

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/UKfT7/289/

Comment: @97ldave, yes like that! :D

Comment: here is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150275/jquery-input-select-all-on-focus

Comment: @97ldave, thanks. I'll attached the script to my kendo numeric box and see if it works. I need it to work on multiple browsers, so testing shall ensue. Thanks.

Comment: a variation http://jsfiddle.net/krustev/TrJVK/ from Telerik

Comment: One more question, if I needed this change to apply to many numeric textboxes and not just one or a few. Is there a way to apply to all kendo numeric textboxes?