# Jquery, Bootstrap - trigger click event on modal hide and select text in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

How can I select text inside input when the modal is closed? Below code is working - when I click the input field, alert is coming up and text is selected.  On **modal hide event** alert is shown, but the text is not selected. What is going on here?

JS Code:

```
// Sellect text
$('.user').on('click', '#name', function(){
        $(this).select();
        alert(1);
    });
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(){

    $('.user').find('#name').trigger('click');

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="user">
  <p>Name
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $user->name ?>" readonly="readonly">
  </p>
</div>
```

**SOLUTION**

I found out that instead of using **hide.bs.modal** event, I should use **hidden.bs.modal** event. In that case the script is working.

Comment: try: `$(document).find('.user #name').click()` or `$(body).find('.user #name').click()` - the modal is added to the dom after therefore it can't find `.user`

Comment: can you add a demo that replicates your issue so we can better help you debug your problem?

Comment: @indubitablee - I will try to replicate it in fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.focus doesn't work for some reason it will not allow you to focus the element until the modal is fully unloaded. I even tried changing the event to hidden.bs.modal that fires after hide.bs.modal and it doesn't matter.

A workaround i have found is to use setInterval and check to see if the body has class "modal-open" once it doesn't then fire focus event

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  var waitForClose = window.setInterval(function() {
    if ($('body').hasClass('modal-open') == false) {
      $('.user').find('#name').trigger('focus');
      window.clearInterval(waitForClose)
    }
  }, 100);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/61sc4Ldr/

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I just changed to the **hidden.bs.modal** event, and the script is working without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that instead of using hide.bs.modal event, I should use hidden.bs.modal event. In that case the script is working.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where is the text field you're referring to. In the modal element or not.
Assuming you already specified in the script that the document is ready (`$(document).ready(..)`, or loaded that script after the html elements are created in the html) You can try calling `$( "#name" ).focus(function() { $(this).select(); } );` in the close event.

Comment: Ok. Here is a [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150275/jquery-input-select-all-on-focus) I found that might help with that. I assume you're in the correct path because the alert shows up, but something else minor is not making that happen.