# :input[type='text'] selector is affecting links tags <a> in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have bootstrap form in my website
when a user focus on textfield the page don't scroll to view
so i found this JQuery code and apply it

```
$(":input[type='text']").focus(function () {
        var e = $(this);
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: e.offset().top - 100
        }, 400)
```

it is working but it is also affecting the links in the page

```
<a href="/login">create your account.</a>
```

when i click the link it does the scroll to the top of the page if i click it again it goes to the login page. I have to click the link two times to go the login page.

did i miss something? as i know my Jquery code is obviously selecting input of type text why it is affecting the  tags

Comment: You probably meant `$("input[type='text']")`. I don't know why you added the `:` in front.

Comment: did you check if there are other listeners for `<a>` tag in the code somewhere? You can inspect your `<a>` tag and click on Event Listeners tab in console and see what all registered handlers are for your tag

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w6k920x8/  That selector does not match the element.  Some other logic is causing your issue, but not this particular selector.

Comment: @connexo I just found this selector in w3school jquery documentation [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_input.asp)

Comment: I don't think you can combine that with an attribute selector like you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150275/jquery-input-select-all-on-focus)

I changed the event from `focus` to `click` and it resolved my problem.

any explanation?