# How does one select the text of the option on focus of the bootstrap combobox? None of the events appear to be firing for onclick or onfocus?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, select, combobox

I have a bootstrap combobox defined and it is working fine except - I tried to get it to select all the text in the preselected option when the control gets focus. None of the events seem to be firing.

I have tried to use jquery `$("#lookup").on("focus",function() {...});` will not fire. I have tried putting `onclick=""` and `onfocus=""` in the tag itself, neither fire.

```
Items to add:<br />
<select class="combobox input-small form-control"  name="normal" id="lookup">
    <option value="0" selected="selected" >type...</option>
    @{
    foreach (var item in Model.MyFoodsDropDown)
        {
        <option value="@item.NDB_No">@item.Shrt_Desc</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

When I click on the combobox it places my cursor at the end of "type..." and I have to do a ctrl-a or use the mouse to select all before typing. It would be really cool for it to select all on focus.

Comment: How can you tell it did not fire?  Did you try to put some console.log('focus fired'); or have you tried debugger keyword? 
and what is body of the function? This way we can make sure that you are selecting all text correctly.

Comment: Also checkout this question, your question might be a duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150275/jquery-input-select-all-on-focus

Comment: I put break points in the debugger and it never fired. I will look at the other question in the hope it has an answer. Thank you.

Comment: $(".combobox").click(function () {$(this).select();}); Worked!!! Sweet! - Got this from the other question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery input select all on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150275/jquery-input-select-all-on-focus)