# Select all text in a 'readonly' <input /> when it gains focus

Tags: javascript, html, html-input

I've got a textbox (set to readonly) and I need its' contents to be selected for easy copy/paste when it gains focus.  Using the code below it only seems to quickly select the text and then unselect it for some reason.

**HTML**

```
<input id='thing' type='text' value='some text' readonly='readonly' />​
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById('thing').onfocus = function(){
    this.select();
};​
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/cfqje/

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067469/selecting-all-text-in-html-text-input-when-clicked

Comment: The Fiddle works for me in Firefox.  IE8 as well.  What browser is not working for you?

Comment: @John Yep, my bad.  I guess i forgot to accept this one.  I have now.

Comment: @MikeChristensen the fiddle does not work for me on Chrome 45

Comment: Hmm, strange, yes it no longer works for me in Chrome 45 either. Changing it to an `onclick` event does work for mouse clicks, but this means it will no longer work when the field is focused via keyboard navigation :/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This seems to be a work around:

```html
<input id='thing' type='text' value='some text' onclick="this.select()" readonly='readonly' />​
```

I guess the problem is that focus doesn't work correctly as the input is readonly.

Comment: Inline script. Tut tut.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use CSS. With `user-select: all;` all text will be selected when a clicking on an element.

Comment: I like this a lot, just be aware that the _"all"_ option might be buggy in Safari, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select#Syntax).

Comment: does not work with `readonly` elments (just tested in Chrome 86)