# Why shouldn't a user/agent be able to select an email address or a number?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

Chrome has rolled out a change to number inputs that is causing this error in my tests

`Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionStart' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('number') does not support selection`

I want to understand why should a number/email input not be select-able (sic)?

Comment: I concur - especially with a number field.  I've posted a question describing this entire issue (and a working workaround solution) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381837/how-to-overcome-whatwg-w3c-chrome-version-33-0-1750-146-regression-bug-with-i

Answer (score 1):

Because the standard defines so.
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-input-element.html#input-type-attr-summary

We have no ways to get precise display values of type=email and type=number because of IDNA, value sanitization, and localization. So setting/getting selection information makes no sense.

Comment: is that any different to a text input? i would say that text is more problematic due to the reasons you have mentioned. at least a number is a number and how would localisation affect an email address?

Comment: "Because the standard defines so" is not a good answer for this. It answers why Chrome has implemented this behavior, but the answer to the question should include a description of ***why*** the standard defines so.