# Limit the user's input in an input number to 4 digits

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

How can I prevent (usign maybe Angular) the user from entering more than 4 numbers in a an simple number like this one :

```
<input type="number">
```

I used `ng-maxlength`, and `max` attributes, but those attributes as specified by w3.org specs and the official website Angular, do not prevent the user from adding more numbers.

What I want is that the input stops in 4 digits, like adding in somehow a mask or something to it.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945192/how-to-make-jquery-inputmask-work-with-input-type-number

Comment: Use maxlength="4", not ng-maxlength

Comment: Meaning that It's not possible anymore ? (As the post says)

Comment: You can do it by using a directive. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701205/how-can-you-limit-the-value-from-input-using-angularjs

Comment: @Vi100 `maxlength`is not a valid attribute for a Number input

Comment: Here are some solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-to-add-maxlength-for-html5-input-type-number-element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using JavaScript:

**HTML**

`<input type="number" oninput="checkNumberFieldLength(this);">`

**JavaScript**

```
function checkNumberFieldLength(elem){
    if (elem.value.length > 4) {
        elem.value = elem.value.slice(0,4); 
    }
}
```

I would also suggest to make use of the `min` and `max` HTML attributes for the input Number element, if it applies in your case.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/nxtytq46/2/)

[**W3c: input Number**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html)

Answer (score 5):

Well, as somebody stated above maxlength doesn't work with inputs of type number, so you can do it this way:

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" maxlength="4">
```

of course, this will do if it's not a requirement to have input type="number"

Answer (score 2):

Using `ng-pattern` with a regex

\d : digits

{4} : 4 times

```
<input type="number" ng-pattern="/^\d{4}$/" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a function in your controller like this

```
angular.module("my-app", [])
    .controller('my-controller', function($scope) {
        $scope.checkInput = function() {
            if (input.value.length > 4) {
                input.value = input.value.slice(0,4);
            }
        });
    });
```

Then in your view you can do something like this

```
<input type="number" max="9999" ng-input="checkInput()" />
```

**Warning**: The max attribute will only work for the spinner. The user will still be able to enter numbers higher than that. Here's an example

```html
<input type="number" max="9999" />
```

Comment: Hey by the way, only the `max="9999"` hackaround workd perfectly !

Comment: No, you can still go around this by typing in the numbers manually. It only works for the spinner

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using modernizr and jquery.

I've made an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/5Lv0upnj/

```
$(function() {
    // Check if the browser supports input[type=number]
    if (Modernizr.inputtypes.number) {
        $('input[type=number]').keypress(function(e) {
            var $this = $(this),
                maxlength = $this.attr('maxlength'),
                length = $this.val().length;

            if (length >= maxlength)
                e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: He doesn't mentioned even jQuery and it can easily done with Angular without any other library.