# Unable to type into number input with FuncUnit

Tags: jasmine, funcunit

I'm using FuncUnit with Jasmine to test my web application, and one issue I've run into consistently relates to typing into an input of type number.

```
<input type="number" min="0.01" step="0.01" pattern="[0-9]+([\.|,][0-9]+)?" class="form-control m-wrap m-ctrl-large" placeholder="10" onkeypress=" return isDecimalKey(event); ">
```

The `isDecimalKey` method basically checks typecodes to make sure that the user is entering a number or decimal point:

```
function isDecimalKey(e) {
    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode !== 46 && charCode > 31
        && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

When typing into the input manually, I'm able to highlight the current value with Ctrl+A, delete it with either backspace or the delete key, and enter a new value. However, when trying to do the same with FuncUnit, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionStart' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('number') does not support selection.
```

I've tried the following methods of insertion:

```
F('input').visible().click().type('[ctrl]a[ctrl-up][delete] 6');
F('input').visible().click().type('[\b][\b] 6');
F('input').visible().click().type('6');
F('input').visible().dblclick().type('6');
```

So far, none of the above has worked. What is the best way for me to go about manipulating this input's value? Thanks!

Comment: this is because of chrome bug (?) not supporting selection properties on input with type number:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177489/selectionstart-selectionend-on-input-type-number-no-longer-allowed-in-chrome

Comment: ...and it looks like it might have been fixed in the newer version of syn library that funcunit is using: https://github.com/bitovi/syn/pull/116