# Type Email doesn't support selectionrange

Tags: javascript, jquery, email, html-input, onfocus

I'm trying to set my cursor to the position of the beginning when I'm on focus of a text box. This is what I have:

```
$("ID").focus(function () {
    var input = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        input.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
    }, 0);
});
```

But I get this error every time I try to load the script:

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'setSelectionRange' on 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('email') does not support selection.

Guess I can't use `setSelectionRange` on emails. So, any other solutions on how to set my cursor position in the input text box (without changing the type email)?

Comment: There is no way around it if you want to keep the `type="email"`. The `type="number"` has the same issue... you could voice your opinion in the [discussion on w3.org](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=24796) (it is specifically for number inputs; I haven't searched for a email type input discussion). Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177489/selectionstart-selectionend-on-input-type-number-no-longer-allowed-in-chrome

Answer (score 5):

It is true, it seems that there is a bug when using the `setSelectionRange` function for email input. So what can be done is to modify the type of the input so that `setSelectionRange` works and not an error.

```
$('#ID').focus(function () {
    var input = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(input).attr('type', 'text');
        input.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
        $(input).attr('type', 'email');
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: This solution works great. I'd set the timeout value to `1` though - `100` is slow enough to be noticeable.