# Keydown event issue on HTML textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a field that accepts the year, so I have created

```
input type="number"
```

and implemented **keydown event** to restrict user to enter more than 4 digits.

Now I'm facing an issue and need help in figuring out the logic. Following is the case:

- Enter 4 digits in the textbox
- Select entered text using SHIFT + Arrow Keys

Now if you type a number it should replace the data but since I have barred it, it will not. Need to cover this case.

Also find code in following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5a0kh9np/).

I also have lot of css and validation on `input[type=number]`, so cannot change to `input[type=text]`.

Also same form is used on mobile devices, and when user selects textbox, numeric keyboard should appear.

#### Edit 1

while searching for option, I found a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Q23E/) that could direct us to right direction.
Issue here also is `input[type=number]` does not support *selection* property. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177489/selectionstart-selectionend-on-input-type-number-no-longer-allowed-in-chrome)

As an alternative, we have decided to move to `input[type=tel]`. This would work in similar fashion, but will allow us to use maxLength attribute. Still if anyone has a better way, please share.

Comment: MaxLength attribute does not work for input[type=number] [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-to-add-maxlength-for-html5-input-type-number-element)

Comment: Please put the relevant code **inside** your question

Comment: The question you reference looks like a duplicate of your question.

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah I'm sorry if its duplicate. I tried to search but I guess my search was not good enough. Can you kindly share the link? Thanks

Comment: Also @RGraham I have added a reference for a jsfiddle link. For your reference http://jsfiddle.net/5a0kh9np/

Comment: You could try saving in a variable the current value of the input when the user press a key, and let the user change it. Then, check: if the new value has more than 4 digits, replace it with the previous one(this happens inmediately so the user won't notice it),

Comment: @pablito.aven I have considered this as my last resort option. Allow 5 digits and strip 5th digit on blur event. This might cover few more cases, but still its a work around. Was thinking a way to solve it in a proper way.

Comment: @Rajesh But doing that way, if the user has four digits and inserts a new one in the middle it fails. What I said is a quite clean workaround

Comment: `tel` allows `+#*` etc, and possibly other characters.

Comment: @Rajesh I have updated my answer to support `tel` and not allow non-numerical characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="tel" class="year" maxlength="4" data-temp="">
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('input', '.year', function(){
    var txt = $(this).val();
    if(isNaN(txt) || txt > 9999){
        $(this).val( $(this).data('temp') );
        return;
    }
    $(this).data('temp', txt);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5a0kh9np/10/)

Comment: Where do you need jQuery code in addition to maxlength? Are there any browsers wich support `type=number` but do not support `min` and `max`?

Comment: And this is a bad way as when you assign a old value you move the cursor to the end of input regardless where it was before.

Comment: @Qwertiy min and max are supported but they do not restrict user from entering values out of range. Also as I have mentioned, I will strip last digit and not revert to previous value.

Comment: As bad way I ment cursor moving. It's logical if it keeps its place. No objections against maxlength. And about brouser support: I asked if there are browsers wich DO support NUMBER and DON'T support MIN/MAX at the same time. You wrote only about min/max support.

Comment: @Rajesh, any change of the value will move the cursor, so maybe it would be better to do such things on `blur`?

Comment: @Qwertiy You are right and even I considered to do same. Also I dont have answer to your question "if there are browsers wich DO support NUMBER and DON'T support MIN/MAX at the same time" but i guess there aren't any but not sure. and thanks.

Comment: @Rajesh, my gess is the same, but I don't know.

Comment: There is a row with digits on the keyboard - you don't handle keys from it.

Comment: Fix: `$(this).val().length == 4 &&
        (e.keyCode > 95 &&
        e.keyCode < 106 ||
        e.keyCode > 47 &&
        e.keyCode < 58)` - http://jsfiddle.net/5a0kh9np/5/

Comment: I can still type `88eeeee88` :)

Comment: @Qwertiy Since `type="number"` allows `e`, `-` and `.` (and Chrome overrides this -- try it with your solution) I think it's best to just use `type="tel"` instead. I have shortened my answer significantly with this change.

Comment: You can prevent `e`, `-` and `.`. Anyway, they are processed correcty when `min` and `max` are specified. And I still think, that it is a bad idea to manipulate with input while user is typing something. About tel - as I remember the keyboard on mobile device will differ for `number` and `tel`.

Comment: Care to elaborate on preventing `e`? Other than using delays. Chrome manipulates to allow `e`.  What's the bad idea here? As far as keypads for `number` and `tel` - both have extra buttons so it makes no difference. There is no"just number" keypad.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work , you can use the Regular Express to validate only number and

```
^[0-9\.\-\/]+$
```

and also you can use the **.length** method to insure that you have specific length

Comment: if user selects data and enters new data, it will replace it so length will not exceed. I want to allow this but unable to figure out how?

Comment: @Rajesh: for that you can use just type text if you like to do so ?

Comment: If I use type text, when I open in mobile, it will open qwerty keyboard and not number keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can't submit an invalid value in this case:

```html
<form>
  <input type=number min=0 max=9999 required />
  <input type=submit value=Submit />
</form>
```

Comment: Yup it wont.  but it allows user to enter any number of text, which I dont want.

Comment: @Rajesh, no. If browser supports validation, it won't pass invalid value to your script - you'll get undefined or an empty string. If you are not sure that brouser supports number inputs, you can add `maxlength=4` attribute - it is supported for a long time for text inputs, but is ignored on numeric.

Answer (score 0):

So I have moved my code to `input[type=tel]` and [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5a0kh9np/12/)

If you check, I have added 2 events

- Keydown to restrict from entering any invalid key.
- Blur event to check if entered value is number only or not.

Now you might be thinking, if I have already restricted user to enter only number, how can he enter incorrect value.

#### Explanation

In my implementation, I have used keydown and using keycode, I'm allowing/blocking. Interesting case is when user press and holds shift key.  Now on keydown, I get same keycode but value is different(A special character). So checking the integrity on blur.

A better way would have been handling keypress and keydown together and I'll update fiddle and update my answer, but for now I guess this has solved my problem.

Thanks you all for all comments/answer. Also kindly let me know if there are any better ways to implement.