# Arrow keys not working in firefox with given javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have one textbox coded like below :

```
<input name="txttelephone" type="text" maxlength="16" id="txttelephone" class="InputTextBox" onkeypress="return NumbersOnly(event);" required />
```

And javascript function is like below :

```
function NumbersOnly(e) {
    var unicode = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
    if (unicode != 8) {
        if (unicode < 48 || unicode > 57) {

            if (unicode == 9)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now When I run this in chrome arrow keys working proper but in firefox arrow key is not working. Not getting what is the issue.

Please help me with this.

Thanks,

Dipa

Comment: Refer to following page for [Char - keyCodes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes). You are returning true only for number keys above qwerty keyboard. This will not even support num pad.

Comment: Maybe this page can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597060/detecting-arrow-key-presses-in-javascript

Comment: Why you don't use input type number?

Comment: @jcubic input type number allows you to enter string. Also it does not have `maxLength` property.

Comment: Refer following [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439723/keydown-event-issue-on-html-textbox).

Comment: @Rajesh you can type only `e` because it can be part of float point number https://jsfiddle.net/44e5e3h0/

Comment: @jcubic My apologies then. But still I'd recommend using input type="tel". Number adds spinner features which might cause issues for mobile number field and you will have to write extra css just to hide it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to exclude arrow key codes. Try following modification in your code.

```
function NumbersOnly(e) {
    var unicode = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
    if (unicode != 8) {
        if (unicode < 48 || unicode > 57) {

            if (unicode == 9 || IsArrows(e) )
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
function IsArrows (e) {
       return (e.keyCode >= 37 && e.keyCode <= 40); 
}
```