# How to allow user to add only one value at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to allow user to enter value at only one box at a time.
For eg: if user enter months the days field should not allow him to enter value.
Can I disable the other field if user enter value in any of them ?
Also it only takes numbers.

[image: dad]

Here is my html

```
<td class="ctext" width="13%"> Reset Frequency in Months/Days
    </td>
    <td class="ctext" style="display:inline-block">
        <label for="frMnth" style="display:block">Month</label>
        <input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="frMnth" name="frMnth" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
        <label for="frDays" style="display:block">Days</label>
        <input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="frDays" name="frDays" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
    </td>
```

And this is script to type number only using Onkeypress.

```
function isNumber(evt) {
evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
}
return true;}
```

Can I disable the field using Onkeypress ?

Comment: instead of onKeyPress try `onBlur`.

Comment: Why not use a single <input> box with a <select> box?

Comment: try this: https://jsfiddle.net/vk9dkaec/

Comment: thank u bt it also tacke characters there

Comment: If you want you can tackle..try to merge your code..

Comment: To block a key from entering, use `keydown` and for invalid keys use `evt.preventDefault()`. Also keyCode `48 - 57` will block number keys that are above qwerty keyboard. This will not block numpad. Please refer following post [Keydown event issue on HTML textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439723/keydown-event-issue-on-html-textbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/1011/

**HTML:**

```
<td class="ctext" width="13%"> Reset Frequency in Months/Days</td>
<td class="ctext" style="display:inline-block">
    <label for="frMnth" style="display:block">Month</label>
    <input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="frMnth" name="frMnth" />
    <label for="frDays" style="display:block">Days</label>
    <input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="frDays" name="frDays" />
</td>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("blur", ".textfield", function() {
        var ele = $(this);
        if (ele.val()) {

            if (isNaN(ele.val())) {
                alert("Only numbers please");
                return false;
            }
            $(".textfield").not(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        } else {
            $(".textfield").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

**Alternative solution without JS**

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/1012/

**HTML:**

```
<td class="ctext" width="13%"> Reset Frequency in Months/Days</td>
<td class="ctext" style="display:inline-block">
    <label for="frMnth" style="display:block">Month/Days</label>
    <input type="number" class="textfield" value="" id="frMnth" name="frMnth" />
    <select>
        <option value="month">Month</option>
        <option value="days">Days</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Change the input type to `number`. Let browser take care of the `number only`requirement. Of course you can add JS for further validations.

Answer (score 0):

Write JQuery

```
$(".textfield").keypress( function() {
    if($("#frMnth").val().length > 0) {
       $("#frDays").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    else if($("#frDays").val().length > 0) {
       $("#frMnth").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    else {
       $("#frMnth").removeAttr("disabled"); 
       $("#frDays").removeAttr("disabled"); 
    }
});
```