# The input element's type ('email') does not support selection, Ionic v6

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, input

i have this error that triggers as soon as there is a change in my ion-input.

I can change the type with 'text' to fix the problem but then the autocomplete email is not functional.

Thank you for your answers !

Error:

```
index-06cd27b1.js:1986 DOMException: Failed to execute 'setSelectionRange' on 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('email') does not support selection.
    at Input.valueChanged (http://localhost:4200/node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-input_entry_js.js:236:24)
```

Code :

```
     <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="floating">
              <ion-icon name="mail-outline"></ion-icon>
              Your email</ion-label
            >
            <ion-input
              type="email"
              autocomplete="email"
              placeholder="my-mail@gmail.com"
              [formControlName]="'email'"
            >
            </ion-input>
          </ion-item>
```

Version:
"@ionic/angular": **"6.0.7"**,
Angular : **"^13.1.4"**

Comment: Fixed to downgrade version : @ionic/angular

Comment: Why the downvote. I searched for same and only found bad workarounds https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53850435/find-if-text-is-selected-for-input-type-number. the solution of beta version worked. `npm i @ionic/angular@6.0.8-dev.1644430127.1b9bb92` . the question is written clear with version information and the solution is promising that in upcomming version the workaround is not needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue starting today: @ionic/angular@6.0.2, Angular@13.2.2.

This is a known bug, you can check out the issue [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/24753). As stated in the thread, there's a dev version of the package you can use as a temp fix before 6.0.8 is released. It worked perfectly for me.

```
@ionic/angular@6.0.8-dev.1644430127.1b9bb92
```