# add text to an input type email angular jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, selection-api

I am trying to add text to input type email without success
here is how I am trying to do it

```
 $scope.lastFocused;
  angular.element("input[type='text'], input[type='url'], input[type='email'], input[type='password'], input[type='search'], input[type='tel'], textarea").focus(function() {

    $scope.lastFocused = document.activeElement;
  });

  $scope.insertText = function(text) {
    var input = $scope.lastFocused;
    console.log(input);
    if (input == undefined) { return; }
    var scrollPos = input.scrollTop;
    var pos = input.selectionStart;
    var front = (input.value).substring(0, pos);  
    var back = (input.value).substring(pos, input.value.length); 
    input.value = front+text+back;
    pos = pos + text.length;

    input.scrollTop = scrollPos;
    console.log(angular.element(input).val());
    angular.element(input).trigger('input');

 };
```

I think the problem has to do with the fact that I am trying to trigger an input of type text and email does not support `input.selectionStart;`. I get the error

> Failed to read the 'selectionStart' property from 'HTMLInputElement':
>   The input element's type ('email') does not support selection.

and for some reason email will not accept a value.

I am using chrome only.
any workarounds would be apreciated

Comment: sorry I know its not the full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to the answer of another post with the same exact type of question as you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21959157/6032583

It looks like you are going to need to find another way because 'selectionStart' is not supported by an input of type email.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize what the real problem was till afterwards thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Still, I think you wish to change `type` attribute of `input` directive.

You can achieve it using only angular, as follows : 
`<input type={{foo.bar}}>`

Later on in your controller change the value of `$scope.foo.bar` accordingly.

Also, anything between `{{}}` is an expression, it could evaluate to anything.

PS: Using Jquery along with AngularJS is kind of redundant and isn't considered a good practice.

Comment: Thank you for your time unfortunately this is a chrome extension therefore you cannot really change the elements on the site (you can but it will be to cumbersome to connect it again to the scope) I will give you a vote because it is possible to change the type angular comes with a jquery lite but it didn't have all the features that I needed.