# Is there a way to tell the cursor/caret position in a number input element in firefox/chrome?

Tags: javascript, html

so there's this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48150864/1173856 but it doesn't work in Firefox or Chrome when the input type is a number. In those cases `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` are both null.

```js
document.getElementById('foobar').addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  console.log('Caret at: ', e.target.selectionStart)
})
```

```html
<input id="foobar" type="number" />
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the spec [`selectionStart` only works for `text`, `search`, `tel`, `url` and `password`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#input-type-attr-summary).

Perhaps you can use `text` instead and use `regex` to accept only numbers.

There is [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177489/selectionstart-selectionend-on-input-type-number-no-longer-allowed-in-chrome) which has already discussed this. There should be alternative ways you can implement to help for your case.

Comment: Yes, and in IE, it doesn't matter that the type is number, the input will eat characters so if only numbers need, js validator is better for it.