# Errors using useRef with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use useRef as shown below with typescript strict set to On, but I keep getting 'Object is possibly 'undefined'.

```
  const inputRef = React.useRef();
  const updateSelectionStart = () =>
    setSelectionStart(inputRef.current.selectionStart);
```

I also tried with this:

```
const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
and
const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
```

And nothing.

Any suggestions about how to do it without typescript errors?

Comment: `inputRef.current` is possibly `undefined`

Comment: I know, I just cannot find a way to make it work. A null check won't work in this case either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by doing this:

```
const updateSelectionStart = () => {
    setCursorPosition(inputRef.current!.selectionStart || 0);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using typescript optional chaining feature as below:

```js
const inputRef = React.useRef();
  const updateSelectionStart = () =>
    setSelectionStart(inputRef.current?.selectionStart);
```

Comment: I also tried that but then I get: Property 'selectionStart' does not exist on type 'never'.

Comment: Take a look at this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40017467/5456476