# Console.log error when clicking an input type="date"

Tags: html

I'm using HTML5 and adding an `input` with a `type="date"` for a date picker, but when I have Developer Tools open, every time I click in my `input` I get the following error displayed.

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'selectionEnd' property on 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('date') does not support selection

Although it's not causing an issue to the user, ideally I don't want the error and was wondering if anyone has come across this and how to fix it.

This is my HTML:

```
<input id="startDate" class="form-control text-uppercase" type="date" />
```

Screenshot of my console.log:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Could you share me more of your code? When I run your code in JSFiddle, I don't find any error messages. Please share me any javascript code which is "related" to this element

Comment: selectionEnd property is not available for Date type, check the [this](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#do-not-apply)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an answer to a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21959157/14956277).

Essentially, Chrome is [not currently supporting](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#do-not-apply) selection for inputs except the `text`, `search`, `tel`, `url`, and `password` types. You are triggering `selectionEnd` by clicking into the input; there's nothing wrong with your code.

The current suggested workaround is to set your input's type to `text` and use the [pattern](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) attribute to ensure valid input although that will not allow you to use the browser-provided date picker if one exists.