# How to get the caret position inside input type="number" element?

Tags: javascript, html, selection-api

Based on this [selectionStart/selectionEnd on input type="number" no longer allowed in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177489/selectionstart-selectionend-on-input-type-number-no-longer-allowed-in-chrome) and my own experiments, I understand that `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` are null inside `<input type="number">` elements. The question is, is there no way to get the caret position at all?

I tried using `window.getSelection()`, as suggested here: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-find-the-caret-inside-a-contenteditable-element-955a5ad9bf81 but this also seems to return 0, and not the actual caret position.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `type` attribute in `target` object:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
input.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  const {target} = e;
  target.setAttribute("type", "text")
  console.log(target.selectionStart, target.selectionEnd)
})
```

```html
<input type="number" />
```

Comment: Not sure what this does e.g. when the user has a mobile keyboard open. Does it switch from numeric to full when you switch the types? And anyway, it's a hack which I also read in the links above, I'd rather have a "clean" solution, thanks.

Comment: Not a working solution. The moment you change the field type, it re-focuses itself and you lost existing caret selection.