# React: how to use event.data in onBeforeInput handler without TypeScript error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So the event received by an `onBeforeInput` handler is typed as `React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>`. This is quite a general type, and doesn't include the `data` property.

As far as I'm aware the events that `onBeforeInput` receives (`nativeEvent`s being `KeyboardEvent` in Firefox, `TextEvent` in Chrome) will have the `data` property.

What's the right way to write a handler that uses `event.data` without TypeScript complaining that `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>'`?

```
onBeforeInput={(e) => {
  handleInput(e.data);
  e.preventDefault();
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found you can also do the following and you'll have no type errors:

```
onBeforeInput={(event: React.CompositionEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const data = event.data
}}
```

If you want to see what the next value in the input would be with the next value you can do the following:

```
onBeforeInput={(event: React.CompositionEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const str = event.currentTarget.value
  const sub = event.data
  const posStart = event.currentTarget.selectionStart || 0
  const posEnd = event.currentTarget.selectionEnd || posStart

  const nextValue = `${str.slice(0, posStart)}${sub}${str.slice(posEnd)}`
}}
```

Comment: Please note that selection [does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21177489/506695) for inputs with `type="number"`.

Answer (score 1):

I just check the type [definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts) and found this,

type of `e` is `FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>`,

Then the `FormEvent` is defined as,

```
interface FormEvent<T = Element> extends SyntheticEvent<T> {
}
```

The `FormEvent` is extended the `SyntheticEvent`, which defined as,

```
interface SyntheticEvent<T = Element, E = Event> extends BaseSyntheticEvent<E, EventTarget & T, EventTarget> {}
```

And when I check the definition of `BaseSyntheticEvent`, I found this,

```
interface BaseSyntheticEvent<E = object, C = any, T = any> {
    nativeEvent: E;
    currentTarget: C;
    target: T;
    bubbles: boolean;
    cancelable: boolean;
    defaultPrevented: boolean;
    eventPhase: number;
    isTrusted: boolean;
    preventDefault(): void;
    isDefaultPrevented(): boolean;
    stopPropagation(): void;
    isPropagationStopped(): boolean;
    persist(): void;
    timeStamp: number;
    type: string;
}
```

Here we don't have a property call `data`. Then I just saw that there is a type call, `CompositionEvent` which extends `SyntheticEvent`.

```
interface CompositionEvent<T = Element> extends SyntheticEvent<T, NativeCompositionEvent> {
    data: string;
}
```

And it has the field `data`;

So I did,

```
<input type="text" onBeforeInput={(e:SyntheticEvent) => { 
        let event = e as CompositionEvent; 
        console.log(event.data); 
}} />
```

Or,

```
interface CustomEvent extends SyntheticEvent {
  data ?: string
}
<input type="text" onBeforeInput={(event:CustomEvent) => { 
        console.log(event.data); 
}} />
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! This doesn't seem like the worst workaround.. but seems wrong to have to cast the object to an unrelated event type..

Comment: I don't see an other solution except using base type of event handlers ( `SyntheticEvent` ) directly ( Something like using interface type instead of concrete type in oop )

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is:

```
onBeforeInput={(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  handleInput(e.nativeEvent.data);
  e.preventDefault();
}}
```

This is because react sends back a wrapper (SyntheticEvent) around the native event. This SyntheticEvent does not have a data property, so typescript is telling you the truth. Luckily react still provides a reference to the native event at `nativeEvent`. Keep in mind that typescript treats properties like `data` as `any` on the HTMLInputEvent so you'll need to be careful to handle all possible values that could exist there.

Comment: The data property _does_ exist on the SyntheticEvent.. I'm not sure if it exists on the native event. Regardless, trying to access it on the native event just gives the same problem. "Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Event'".