# AngularJS KeyUp change value to keyCode

Tags: angularjs

Fiddle - http://plnkr.co/edit/NizmbUMHblixAUPfQF2G?p=preview

I'm learning [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup), and I wanted to try something simple....

Every time I type in a textbox I want to see it's [keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode), (I'm using jQuery in the following function I'm trying to rewrite in this example as jQuery [standardizes the keycode event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) in this case for cross browser consistency)

```
// Get Keycode/Which
$("[data-action=outputkeycode]").on("keyup", function(e) {
  $(this).val(e.which);
}).on("click", function() {
  $(this).select();
});
```

Because I'm trying to update the textbox being typed to find the keyCode I figured I'd apply `event.keyCode` in the value, but it's not working.

```
<body ng-app="">
  <input ng-keyup="event=$event" value="{{ event.keyCode }}">
</body>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="">
    <input ng-keyup="event=$event" value="{{ event.keyCode }}">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a comment in general. I read that your not really supposed to add jQuery to angular, check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: do you want to show the key code in input is that all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to show the key code in the `input` then you can use below code

```
<input ng-keydown="event=$event.keyCode; $event.preventDefault()" ng-model="event">
```

when key is pressing down which happens before the `ng-keyup` we will assign the `keycode` to `event` scope variable, then we prevent its default action which is type the actual character in textbox.

and assign the `ng-model="event"` here the text box gets the value of `event` scope variable

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="">
    <input ng-keydown="event=$event.keyCode; $event.preventDefault()" ng-model="event">
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**Update**

select the text on click in textbox.

You can create a angular directive to select the textbox text, here is a good [directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995884/select-text-on-input-focus)

and here is the [updated demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/CjSRfoK4kVbhBi3ydmDB?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you, how would I select the added value via a click event? (I assume it'd be ng-click, but `this.select` isn't working for me).

Comment: umm sorry i didnt get it can u please describe it bit more with an example if its possible? :)

Comment: After the keyCode is added I'm trying to click that input textbox to select it. - http://plnkr.co/edit/KsoGzXSThEsqLf3FGDI9?p=preview

Comment: Learning Angular is going to be pretty interesting. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="">
    <input ng-keyup="keyCode=$event.keyCode" ng-model="keyCode">
  </body>
</html>
```