# Ionic, keep button above keypad on iOS

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I need the "OK" button at the bottom of this page to stay above the keypad when opened. It works on Android as you can see in the screenshot on the left, but not in iOS (screenshot on the right).

Moreover, as you can see the "select-on-focus" directive doesn't work in iOS. And the keypad should the numeric keypad (phone pad) on iOS...and it's not.

Here's a video: https://youtu.be/_bOWGMGesgk

[image: Android] [image: iOS]

Here's the code:

```
<div class="wrapperFlex withNextButton">
<div class="itemTitle">
    <div class="text">
        {{'paramQuestions.weight' | translate }}
    </div>
</div>

<div id="weightdata" class="itemParameters weightdataclass row">
    
    <input class="weightinput" type="number" name="userweight" ng-min="{{data.minWeight}}" ng-max="{{data.maxWeight}}" ng-model="data.realWeight" ng-change="updateViewGenVol(data.weightunit, data.userweight, data.BLfactorValue);saveUserWeight()" select-on-focus required></input>
    <div class="weightunitradios">
        <ion-checkbox class="checkboxes checkbox-blueboardline" ng-model="data.weightunit" ng-true-value="'kg'" ng-false-value="'lbs'" ng-change="saveWeightUnit(); changeMinMax(); convertWeightInput(); saveUserWeight();">kg</ion-checkbox>
        <ion-checkbox class="checkboxes checkbox-blueboardline" ng-model="data.weightunit" ng-true-value="'lbs'" ng-false-value="'kg'" ng-change="saveWeightUnit(); changeMinMax(); convertWeightInput(); saveUserWeight();">lbs</ion-checkbox>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

directives.js:

```
.directive('selectOnFocus', function ($timeout) {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          var focusedElement = null;

          element.on('focus', function () {
              var self = this;
              if (focusedElement != self) {
                  focusedElement = self;
                  $timeout(function () {
                      self.select();
                  }, 10);
              }
          });

          element.on('blur', function () {
              focusedElement = null;
          });
        }
  }
})
```

Comment: To get the phone keyboard, you have to use <input type="tel">

Comment: ok thanks for this. Do you have any idea on the other problems ?

Comment: maybe try [this directive](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14996261/5635057), it seems to works just fine

Comment: @nicfo thanks but this directive doesn't work for type = number, any other idea please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the keyboard/scroll issue, I didn't find better than this directive (only for ios):

```
.directive('keyboardResize', function ($ionicScrollDelegate) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

            function onKeyboardShow (e) {
                element.css('bottom', e.keyboardHeight + 'px');
                $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle(attrs.delegateHandle).resize();
                console.log("ouiaaaaaaaaa")
            };
            function onKeyboardHide (e) {
                element.css('bottom', '');
                $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle(attrs.delegateHandle).resize();
            };

            if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
              ionic.on('native.keyboardshow', onKeyboardShow, window);
              ionic.on('native.keyboardhide', onKeyboardHide, window);

              scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                  ionic.off('native.keyboardshow', onKeyboardShow, window);
                  ionic.off('native.keyboardhide', onKeyboardHide, window);
              });
            }

        }
      }
    })
```

Comment: Man, add an example using this directive from a template please. And what's delegateHandle? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ionic actually supports this feature by default. Have a look at the `keyboard-attach` attribute directive.

> keyboard-attach is an attribute directive which will cause an element to float above the keyboard when the keyboard shows. Currently only supports the ion-footer-bar directive.

```
<ion-footer-bar align-title="left" keyboard-attach class="bar-assertive">
   <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

Source: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/keyboardAttach/

Comment: thanks but `keyboard-attach` doesn't work here because i need the view's height to reduce, and if I `attach` everything to the keyboard, it doesn't end well !