# How to fire keyboard events in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, keyboard-events

I'm giving a value to a `textbox` and then giving focus to it.

```
document.getElementById('textbox').value="abcd";
document.getElementById('textbox').focus();
```

Then, I am creating a keyboard event and trying to fire the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> key combination (trying to select the text inside the `textbox`) by writing the following code:

```
var myEvent = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');

myEvent.initKeyEvent("keypress", true, true, window, true, false, false, false, 0, 97);

document.getElementById('textbox').dispatchEvent(myEvent);
```

But the above code doesn't select the text inside the textbox.

*How to select the text creating the keyboard event ?*

Comment: Similiar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067469/selecting-all-text-in-html-text-input-when-clicked

Answer (score 3):

You can't trigger browser keypress behavior with JavaScript simulated keypresses. You can only trigger your own function. What that means if that if you add a keypress event listener that checks if the <kbd>a</kbd> key is pressed and then does something, you can trigger that behavior, but you can't for example make the browser pull up it's "find" bar when you trigger <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. That would be a security issue.

The appropriate way would be to write your own function for selecting and fire it whenever you need it.

This should do what you're looking for: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/OFOSuda/2/edit)**

```
<input type="text" id="my-input" value="Some text.">
```

JavaScript:

```
var myInput = document.getElementById('my-input');

myInput.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.focus();
  this.select();
});

var event = new Event('click');
myInput.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: I understand that this is a security issue but still, is there any way to achieve this functionality ?

Comment: @user2856930 see the demo I posted.

Comment: The example that you have posted to select the text is fine, but I need to achieve other things too with the key combinations.

Comment: @user2856930 such as? You have to ask the question you want answered...how can I know what else you need unless you tell me?

Comment: Such as "Opening a new Tab", "Closing a tab".

Comment: @user2856930 again, that has nothing to do with keypresses. That's just `window.open()` and `window.close()`.

Comment: Mozilla doesn't allow window.close().

Comment: @user2856930 View this demo in Firefox - window.close() works fine. http://plnkr.co/edit/iovbGvita1BNiXOQ029H?p=preview

Comment: Check this... it will not work if u see this in firefox.
http://jsfiddle.net/EvXsk/2/

Comment: @user2856930 of course not! It sounds like you're up to no good. You can only close a window that you opened. Everything you're trying to do would only be useful to someone trying to harm/attack the user. http://jsfiddle.net/EvXsk/3/

Comment: Actually when I open a popup in IE, the parent window automatically closes, I want to achieve the same...