# Greasemonkey - adjust an input field

Tags: greasemonkey

I want to manipulate the following code so that when you click in the search box it selects all the text in the box rather than having to double click or press ctrl+A

The current code is:

```
<input name="sysparm_search" id="sysparm_search" placeholder="Search" 
type="search" class="form-control form-control-search">
```

Is this possible to do with greasemonkey scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way would be the following (using jQuery):

```
$("#sysparam_search").click(function() {
    $(this).select();
});
```

There are some drawbacks associated with this kind of selection, though. See this topic for more details: [Selecting all text in HTML text input when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067469/selecting-all-text-in-html-text-input-when-clicked)