# onclick copy or highlight <code> to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, markdown, clipboard

When person clicks on any `<code>` element it'll auto highlight everything inside plus copy to clipboard. I'm writing articles and there are lots of copy / paste commands being used for SSH. It would be nice if I could shave off a few dozen clicks for the visitor. I get this error when I try the code below:

[image: here is the error i receive]

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'code', function () {
        this.select();
    });
});
```

I write these articles in markdown, and when I export, it's just clean code. I would prefer if I didn't have to use Flash or add a class or id to the html. Instead, just assume everything inside `<code>` should be copied to clipboard on click.

I also just tried this, but still no luck.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('code').focus(function () {
  this.select();
  this.setSelectionRange(0, 9999);
}).mouseup(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

source

[Selecting all text in HTML text input when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067469/selecting-all-text-in-html-text-input-when-clicked)

http://jsfiddle.net/NNqyF/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this is by creating a dumby textarea with the content copying it, then removing the textarea.

```js
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'code', function () {
      $(this).addClass("active")
       textarea =  $("<textarea>").val($(this).html()).height(0).appendTo(document.body).select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
       textarea.remove();
    });
});
```

```css
code {
  background: #555;
  color:white;
}
.active {
  background:#3399ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<code>test2</code>
```

Comment: Just about perfect! Do you think the best way to add highlight effect is to style `code:active { background: red;}`? Any other tips tricks or hints?

Comment: I updated my code. It should work.  After you click, it highlights it.

Answer (score 1):

I've only tested this in chrome, but you can do the following:

```
$('code').on('click', function(e){
  var sel = window.getSelection()
  var r = document.createRange()
  r.selectNodeContents(e.target.closest('code'))
  sel.removeAllRanges()
  sel.addRange(r)
  document.execCommand('copy')
})
```

It does what yo want it to. Credit should go to these answers: [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/2838358/6872682