# Select all text in input field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following code for selecting all text inside input field:

```
<input id="userName" class="form-control" 
type="text" name="enteredUserName" data-ng-show="vm.userNameDisplayed()" 
    data-ng-model="vm.enteredUserName">
```

and method to select all text:

```
vm.userNameDisplayed = function() {
    var textArea = angular.element('#userName');
    textArea.setSelectionRange(0, vm.enteredUserName.length)
}
```

but after calling this method nothing is selected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067469/selecting-all-text-in-html-text-input-when-clicked

Comment: 1. I don't need to do it on onClick method
2. I have the same code as in provided example

Comment: When do you expect the text to be selected? As soon as user types?

Comment: Secondly, `ng-show` expects an expression that resolves to truthy/falsy. In your case, the function `userNameDisplayed` will be called when the page is rendered. If there is no data at that time, it will not select anything.

Comment: Searching on the title returns [*5,000 results*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+select+all+text+in+input).

Answer (score 1):

Try focusing the textArea first using `textArea.focus();`

```
vm.userNameDisplayed = function() {
    var textArea = angular.element('#userName');
    textArea.focus();
    textArea.setSelectionRange(0, vm.enteredUserName.length)
}
```