# How to auto select/highlight text in a text/input box in elm

Tags: elm

Is there a way in elm to do the same thing as `document.getElementById("test").select()` does in javascript?

I have an input field that I want to act in a very similar way to highlighted share url when you click on share on here on StackOverflow:[image]

Even something like on github when you need to click the element to highlight it is fine: [image]

I know how to do this with ports ([eg.](https://www.reddit.com/r/elm/comments/475bai/selecting_text_input_on_button_click/d0ae33b/)).
But I would prefer to do it directly in Elm. Is this possible? Will it be possible in future versions of Elm?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently a package with a few similar functions at [`elm-lang/dom`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/dom/1.1.1/Dom), but they rely on native Javascript calls. [See the `focus` example here](https://github.com/elm-lang/dom/blob/1.1.1/src/Native/Dom.js#L60-L66).

The [Elm code](https://github.com/elm-lang/dom/blob/1.1.1/src/Dom.elm#L52-L54):

```elm
focus : Id -> Task Error ()
focus =
  Native.Dom.focus
```

and the native code...

```js
function focus(id)
{
    return withNode(id, function(node) {
        node.focus();
        return _elm_lang$core$Native_Utils.Tuple0;
    });
}
```

If you wanted to build a local package that doesn't use ports, you would currently have to build a native package, which would work, but may not be backwards compatible in the future, and you won't be able to list the package publicly.

I would recommend using ports.

Answer (score 1):

In Elm 0.19, `Browser.Dom` has a [`focus`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser.Dom#focus) task that will focus the DOM element with a given id. This will put the cursor in the element (if it is editable), but it will not *select* the text (i.e. highlight it). For that, you would need JavaScript [`select()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067469/selecting-all-text-in-html-text-input-when-clicked). As far as I know, there's not a binding for that in Elm, but it must just be an oversight. It would be very easy to add -- almost the exact same as focus.

For now, if you want the text to be selected, ports are the only option.