# Auto select the content of a matInput using a mat-icon

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have one matInput field and a mat-icon(edit icon). When I click on the edit icon I need to perform the following 
operations

enable the input text box,

sets focus to it,

and auto-selects all the text in that.

Tried '$event.target.select()'. But it is not working.
How can I do that? 
Thanks in advance.

.html file

```
<mat-form-field class="input-style">
 <input matInput[(ngModel)]="name"(click)="$event.target.select()">
  {{value}}
 </mat-form-field>
<button mat-icon-button color="primary">
 <mat-icon (click)="$event.target.select()">edit</mat-icon>
</button>
```

.ts file

```
export class  Sample {
 public value:string ="sample";
}
```

Comment: U can try this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067469/selecting-all-text-in-html-text-input-when-clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `local elementRef var` :

```
<mat-form-field class="input-style">
    <input matInput #inputRef [(ngModel)]="name">
    {{value}}
</mat-form-field>
<button mat-icon-button color="primary">
    <mat-icon (click)="inputRef.select()">edit</mat-icon>
</button>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-text-input)**