# How to select text on click input box in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I am new to JavaScript and building an application in which, using plain JavaScript, I would like to select the text (similar to right clicking and select all) upon click of an element on a web page if the element is of type input. Can this be done? If so how would I go about doing this. Any info would be appreciated.

Comment: Hopefully someone understands what you means because I have no idea what you are asking for.

Comment: I'm looking for the JavaScript, for when I click on any element in an HTML document, if the clicked on element is a text input box, I can simulate right clicking on that element and click "select all" from the context menu

Comment: Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067469/selecting-all-text-in-html-text-input-when-clicked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting all text in HTML text input when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067469/selecting-all-text-in-html-text-input-when-clicked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this script at the bottom of your body tag

```
<script>
  document.querySelectorAll('.js-select-input').forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('click', (e) => e.currentTarget.select())
  })
</script>
```

and for every input that you would like to have this autoselect functionality add the class "js-select-input" as in this example:

```
<input class="js-select-input" value="foo">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `select` method to achieve this.
Use `select` method in the callback function of input's `onfocus` event.
For better understanding, see the following example:

```js
function testFunc(focusedInput) {
  focusedInput.select();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="test-input" type="text" name="test-input" value="default-value" onfocus="testFunc(this)">
  <script>
    function testFunc(focusedInput) {
      focusedInput.select();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```