# How to select whole text of a textbox in ipad safari browser?

Tags: ipad, safari, mobile-safari

i want to select all text on a textbox while user focus on this textbox at that time its text will be selected automatically. Same as .select() javascript function works in firefox or ie. Same functionality i want on ipad safari browser.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7436574/937084):

```
// t is the input field
setTimeout(function() {
    t.setSelectionRange(0, 9999);
}, 1);
```