# Is it possible to select all input text on iphone device when focus / click?

Tags: jquery, iphone, select, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to select all input text on iphone device when focus / click?

Typically for a browser environment one would use:

```
$('input').bind("click focus", function() {
$(this).select();
});
```

This works for desktop browsers but appears unresponsive for iphone and presumably other mobile devices.

Comment: Have you tried adding `touchstart` and `mspointerdown` to the list of events? If this doesn't work, it may be blocked by the mobile OS, like controlling audio levels on video objects is.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. I will give that a go!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically selecting text in an input field on iOS devices (mobile Safari)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272089/programmatically-selecting-text-in-an-input-field-on-ios-devices-mobile-safari)

Answer (score 4):

Basically you have to REARRANGE the events focus, then click, then touchstart

```
$('#myID').on('focus click touchstart', function(e){
$(this).get(0).setSelectionRange(0,9999);
//$(this).css("color", "blue"); FUBAR
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting a (small) timeout works best for me:
The iOS keyboard seems to be called in a delegate or something, as it kept loosing my focus event to be able to select stuff. The `select()` did not work for the same reason.

I fixed it this way:

```
function focusMe(vitem) {
    window.setTimeout(function() { 
      vitem.setSelectionRange(0, 9999);
    }, 10);
}

<input onfocus="focusMe(this)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('focus',function(){
    $(this).get(0).selectionStart=0;
    $(this).get(0).selectionEnd=999;
})
```

I originally found this information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272089/programmatically-selecting-text-in-an-input-field-on-ios-devices-mobile-safari), and there are other things people have tried that have achieved the result.

Comment: `$(this).get(0)` is exactly the same as `this`.

Comment: indeed it is.  How superfluous of me.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
$('input').live("click", function() {
    $('input').each(function(){
        $(this).select();
    });
});
$('input').live("focus", function() {
    $('input').each(function(){
        $(this).select();
    });
});
```