# How to trigger the copy text button in mobile OS(android,ios) using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, copy

As known, when you long tap a text element in a mobile html page, you will get a copy button, which could be clicked to copy the selected text to clipboard.

So is it possible to use javascript to show the copy button?

Or, is there any better solution to guide the user to copy a section of text easily and fast  in a mobile html page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of - [Programmatically trigger copy menu in iOS safari using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442682/programmatically-trigger-copy-menu-in-ios-safari-using-javascript)

No, Its is not possible to trigger clipboard operations through JavaScript. Its restriction imposed for security of data theft.