# .select() function does not work on iOS device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, mobile-safari

I would like to make an input box that, when the user selects it, all the text in the box is selected. So I decided to use the `select()` function, which is what I would like to achieve. However, it works as I expected on desktop browsers, but not on Safari on the iPad. How to fix the problem? Thanks.

```
$('#input').click(function(e){
      $(this).select();
});
```

Comment: I tried the solution there but it does not work . Thanks for your remind.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

according to this SO question([Programmatically selecting text in an input field on iOS devices (mobile Safari)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272089/programmatically-selecting-text-in-an-input-field-on-ios-devices-mobile-safari)), it doesn't work in iOS, and you need to use the `setSelectionRange()` function. in your case, it would be something like this:

```
$(this).get(0).setSelectionRange(0,9999);
```

Comment: That's the answer , thanks