# Select ALL in the input form contents on focus on iOS / Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, focus

I have the following code to select all the contents of my `input` element that has `id="embedurl"`

```
$('#embedurl').focus(function(event) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#embedurl').select();
    }, 0);
});
```

It works fine on desktop, but in iOS nothing gets selected.

Any idea how I could fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it without the _setTimeout_?

Comment: What is the purpose of a timeout set to fire after 0 milliseconds?

Comment: What is expected result ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#embedurl').setSelectionRange(0, 9999);
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6302507/2117077) answer. It worked for me, although the comments on that answer do note some caveats, such as needing to trigger a focus() event first.