# Detecting if HTMLInputElement.select is actually supported

Tags: javascript, ios

People say UA sniffing is bad. So I'm trying to do a feature detection for `HTMLInputElement.select()`.

My reason is that, on iOS mobile devices, the function is supported, but it [does not actually select text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272089/programmatically-selecting-text-in-an-input-field-on-ios-devices-mobile-safari). I want to detect this so that I can use `HTMLInputElement.setSelectionRange()` instead.

I tried this:

```
function checkInputSelectWorks() {
    var testStr = "test";
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.value = testStr;
    input.select();

    return input.selectionEnd == testStr.length;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbq80cq1/)

I thought this would be sufficient, but it seems that `selectionEnd` is set to `testStr.length` even before calling `select()`. How should I go about doing this?

No jQuery, please. It shouldn't be necessary.

**EDIT**: Adding the input element to the DOM did not help. `input.SelectionEnd` becomes 0 when added to DOM, but it still gets updated after `.select()` on iOS without actually selecting text.