# Looking for a better workaround to Chrome select on focus bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit

I have the same problem as the user in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269722/selecting-text-on-focus-using-jquery-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome), which is due to [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=4505) in Webkit. However, the workaround provided will not work for my app. Let me re-state the problem so that you don't have to go read another question:

I am trying to select all the text in a textarea when it gets focus. The following jQuery code works in IE/FF/Opera:

```
$('#out').focus(function(){
  $('#out').select();
});
```

However, in Chrome/Safari the text is selected--very briefly--but then the mouseUp event is fired and the text is deselected. The following workaround is offered in the above links:

```
$('#out').mouseup(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

However, **this workaround is no good for me**. I want to select all text *only* when the user gives the textarea focus. He *must* then be able to select only part of the text if he chooses. Can anyone think of a workaround that still meets this requirement?

Comment: A big +1 for spotting the obvious glaring flaw in the most commonly-suggested solution to the problem.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

How about this?

```
$('#out').focus(function () {
    $('#out').select().mouseup(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).unbind("mouseup");
    });
});
```

Comment: Probably `.one()` is a better way here.

Comment: +1. I don't get why so many people think the basic `preventDefault()` fix is sufficient. It clearly has severe flaws, and yet it's being suggested as the solution everywhere you look. Thank you for solving it. (though yes, I agree with @InviS that `.one()` might be a better way of doing it)

Comment: .one() would be better and this doesn't handle tabbed focus very well.

Comment: Here's how to do this using jQuery's `.one()` as @InviS suggests: `$('#out').focus(function () { $('#out').select().one('mouseup', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }); });`

Answer (score 25):

The accepted answer (and basically every other solution I found so far) does not work with keyboard focus, i. e. pressing tab, at least not in my Chromium 21. I use the following snippet instead:

```
$('#out').focus(function () {
  $(this).select().one('mouseup', function (e) {
    $(this).off('keyup');
    e.preventDefault();
  }).one('keyup', function () {
    $(this).select().off('mouseup');
  });
});
```

`e.preventDefault()` in the `keyup` or `focus` handler does not help, so the unselecting after a keyboard focus seems to not happen in their default handlers, but rather somewhere between the `focus` and `keyup` events.

As suggested by @BarelyFitz, it might be better to work with namespaced events in order to not accidentally unbind other event handlers. Replace `'keyup'` with `'keyup.selectText'` and `'mouseup'` with `'mouseup.selectText'` for that.

Comment: When you unbind events, you could inadvertently unbind other handlers that might be on the input. To prevent this you could use a namespace such as "mouseup.selectText" instead of "mouseup", then only your single event handler will be removed.

Comment: Combined with the namespace hint this is the best solution I've found yet for this sticky wicket and I commend it to the house.

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply:

```
$('#out').focus(function(){
    $(this).one('mouseup', function() {
        $(this).select();
    });
});
```

Seems to work in all major browsers...

Comment: This worked for me. It's worth noting that it doesn't seem to work when you focus on an input through code. To get around this, I use `$('#element').select().focus()` instead of `$('#element').focus()`.

Answer (score 4):

A very slightly different approach would be to separate the focus event from the mouse sequence.  This works really nicely for me - no state variables, no leaked handlers, no inadvertent removal of handlers, and it works with click, tab, or programmatic focus. Code and jsFiddle below -

```
$('#out').focus(function() {
    $(this).select();
});
$('#out').on('mousedown.selectOnFocus', function() {
    if (!($(this).is(':focus'))) {
        $(this).focus();
        $(this).one('mouseup.selectOnFocus', function(up) {
            up.preventDefault();
        });
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tpankake/eob9eb26/27/

Answer (score 2):

Make a `bool`. Set it to `true` after a focus event and reset it after a mouse up event. During the mouse up, if it's `true`, you know the user just selected the text field; therefore you know you must prevent the mouse up from happening. Otherwise, you must let it pass.

```
var textFieldGotFocus = false;

$('#out').focus(function()
{
    $('#out').select();
    textFieldGotFocus = true;
});

$('#out').mouseup(function(e)
{
    if (textFieldGotFocus)
        e.preventDefault();
});

$(document).mouseup(function() { textFieldGotFocus = false; });
```

It's important that you put the mouseup listener that resets the variable on `document`, since it's not guaranteed that the user will release the mouse button over the text field.

Comment: thanks! this inspired an even simpler idea: instead of a listener on document.mouseup, just set the flag to false on out.mouseup: `if(textFieldGotFocus){ e.preventDefault(); textFieldGotFocus = false;}`

Comment: Gosh no. global vars + event handling == recipe for trouble.

Answer (score 2):

```
onclick="var self = this;setTimeout(function() {self.select();}, 0);"
```

Comment: This answer inspired: 
`$("#one").on('focus', null, function() { var $that = $(this); setTimeout(function() { $that.select(); }, 0); });`

Answer (score 2):

Select the text before putting the focus on the input box.

```
$('#out').select().focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

digitalfresh's solution is mostly there, but has a bug in that if you manually trigger .focus() using JS (so not using a click), or if you tab to the field, then you get an unwanted mouseup event bound - this causes the first click that should deselect the text to be ignored.

To solve:

```
var out = $('#out');
var mouseCurrentlyDown = false;

out.focus(function () {
  out.select();

  if (mouseCurrentlyDown) {
    out.one('mouseup', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });  
  }
}).mousedown(function() {
  mouseCurrentlyDown = true;
});

$('body').mouseup(function() {
  mouseCurrentlyDown = false;
});
```

Note: The mouseup event should be on body and not the input as we want to account for the user mousedown-ing within the input, moving the mouse out of the input, and then mouseup-ing.

Answer (score 0):

tpankake's answer converted to a reusable jQuery function..
*(If you upvote this, please also upvote his answer)*

**Load the following AFTER loading the jQuery library:**

```
$.fn.focusSelect = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        var me = $(this);
        me.focus(function () {
            $(this).select();
        });
        me.on('mousedown.selectOnFocus', function () {
            var me2 = $(this);
            if (me2.is(':focus') === false) {
                me2.focus();
                me2.one('mouseup.selectOnFocus', function (up) {
                    up.preventDefault();
                });
            }
        });
    });
};
```

**Use it like this:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // apply to all inputs on the page:
    $('input[type=text]').focusSelect();

    // apply only to one input
    $('#out').focusSelect();
});
```