# Mobile Safari jQuery select() on focus input doesn´t work

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, select, focus

This problem is on iPad IOS6 in mobile Safari.

I wan´t the text in an input to be auto selected when the user clicks the input.

I have a solution that works in a regular browser, like Chrome:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        //Select text on focus for input
        $("input:text").focus(focustext);
    });
    function focustext() {
        var input = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() { 
            input.select();
        },100);
    }
```

But this isn´t working in Safari Mobile.

I have read several threads about this, for example:
[Workaround to Webkit[Chrome/Safari] javascript select on focus bug (when using tab between fields)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227691/workaround-to-webkitchrome-safari-javascript-select-on-focus-bug-when-using-t)
[Selecting text on focus using jQuery not working in iPhone iPad Browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924506/selecting-text-on-focus-using-jquery-not-working-in-iphone-ipad-browsers)

I have tested suggested sollution in a simple dummy, but I can´t get any of them to work on iPad.
http://kraner.se/customers/test.html

I would like the get a working sollution for this.
Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the javascript to this (changed how selection of text is done and how to get input variable):

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        //Select text on focus for input
        $("input:text").focus(focustext);
    });
    function focustext() {
        var input = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            input.selectionStart = 0;
            input.selectionEnd = input.val().length;
        },100);
    }
```

and now it works as intented. inputs with type=number does not seem to work though.

I have tested this on iOS6 and iOS7, and it also works in latest Chrome and IE on Windows 7. IE in compability mode does not work, though.

Comment: One small issue, it should be `input.value.length` instead of `input.val().length`.