# unable to select jQuery dynamic element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

By select, I mean `select()`

My code is this:

```
    $('.show-embed-link').unbind('click');
    $(".show-embed-link").click(function(e){
        var id = $(this).attr("rel");
        e.preventDefault();
        showEmbed(id);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#general_message").focus();
        }, 100);
    });
```

`.show-embed-link` is not dynamic element. It is a `<a>` element.

`showEmbed` will generate a dynamic element.

```
function showEmbed(id) {
        var message = '<iframe width="1000" height="800" src="//storyzer.com/stories/'+id+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
        message = HtmlEncode(message);
        showOverlayForGeneral(message, "Embed work", {'spinner': false, 'extraheight': 90, 'showclose': true});
 }
```

`showOverlayForGeneral` is responsible for generating the dynamic element with the message.

```
function showOverlayForGeneral(message, title, options) {
    options = (typeof options === "undefined") ? {} : options;
    var defaultOptions = {
        "message": "",
        "extraheight": 150,
        "spinner": true,
        "showclose": false
    };

       // code removed because not relevant to this situation...

    $('#general_message').unbind('focus');
    $('#general_message').focus(function () {
        $('#general_message').select().mouseup(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).unbind("mouseup");
        });
    });
}
```

The `focus` code is taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3380493

Currently, my div html is not selected. How can I tell if the select event is happening?

Comment: take a look on `.on()` https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: And how should I use it?

Comment: you have provide a fiddle of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#general_message').unbind('focus');
        $('#general_message').focus(function () {
            $('#general_message').select().click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).unbind("click");
            });
        });
})
```

Comment: Why change the mouseup to click?

Comment: i think you want to focus the div part, so when you click that div then it should be focusing on your div so i just replace the mouseup to click function.@KimStacks

Comment: I don't want to click on the div. I want it to focus via javascript. See my first code block. I used .focus()

Comment: the focus function is inside the div click function so how the focus function work without clicking that div.? i edited my answer see that. @KimStacks