# Select text in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am going in circles here.  Thought I could fix this issue asked a question earlier answered it only to get stuck again.  Have a simple form with multiple panels containing text and numeric input field.  When a user clicks in tabs in or whatever the content of that input field text should be selected. I've started looking at [THIS](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-select-function/) article and also looking at the jquery focus and select.  Nothing seems to be working.  When clicking in the input field nothing seems to be highlighting the text already there.

Thanks

Here are a few things I've tried :

```
$("input[type=text]").focus(function() {
    $(this).select();
});

$('#itemPanel :input[type="text"]').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    console.log("I was clicked in");
  });
});
```

Comment: by "should be highlighted" do you mean it should be selected?

Comment: yes - i'll edit the question

Comment: try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380458/looking-for-a-better-workaround-to-chrome-select-on-focus-bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `on focus`

```
$('input[type=text]').on('focus', function() {
   $(this).select();
});
```

You can also use `mouseup`

```
$('input[type=text]').on('mouseup', function() {
   $(this).select();
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fg1exv3L/)

Answer (score 0):

To autoselect the text in the input box I would recommend using `click`event instead of the `focus` event in your example.

This also seems to be written in the code example link you posted.  http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-select-function/ (Notice how it's using `click` instead of `focus`)

Try this:

```
$("input[type=text]").click(function() {
    $(this).select();
});
```

**--EDIT**

Based on some feedback in the comments, there's a link to another similar question that suggests something like this:

```
$('input[type=text]').focus(function() {
  $('input[type=text]').select().one('mouseup', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Apparently that makes it very hard to unselect if you click it selects again. Here is an answer that deals with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380458/looking-for-a-better-workaround-to-chrome-select-on-focus-bug

Comment: Yes originally I had started with the click event but that didnt work.  Then I put it in an angular.element(document).ready() fucntion but that didnt work either

Comment: Maybe something like it's suggested in here would work? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3380493/280842