# Selecting text on focus using jQuery not working in iPhone iPad Browsers

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

We are developing Web-App for Mobile browsers, we would like text of any input box to get selected whenever input-box get focus. Below answer fixes the issue for Desktop chrome/safari browser. Below solution works fine on Android browser, but not on iPhone/iPad browsers, any solution..

```
$("#souper_fancy").focus(function() { $(this).select() });

$("#souper_fancy").mouseup(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Ref:-

[Selecting text on focus using jQuery not working in Safari and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269722/selecting-text-on-focus-using-jquery-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome)

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272089/programmatically-selecting-text-in-an-input-field-on-ios-devices-mobile-safari

Comment: yes. Thanks Robcat, it worked solution found here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272089/programmatically-selecting-text-in-an-input-field-on-ios-devices-mobile-safari

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer found here 
don't know how to mark this question as duplicate.
[Programmatically selecting text in an input field on iOS devices (mobile Safari)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272089/programmatically-selecting-text-in-an-input-field-on-ios-devices-mobile-safari)

My fix look like this:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           $('div,data-role=page').live('pageshow', function (event) {
               jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse(".ui-page-active form");
               $("input[type='text'], textarea, input[type='password'], input[type='number']").live('mouseup', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
               $("input[type='text'], textarea, input[type='password'], input[type='number']").live('focus', function () {this.setSelectionRange(0, 9999); });             
           });       
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

> **vmouseup**
> *Normalized event for handling touchend or mouseup events*

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/events.html

JS:

```
$("#souper_fancy").focus(function() { 
    $(this).select();
});

$("#souper_fancy").vmouseup(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.execCommand('selectAll');`. However if the user scrolls the page, you will get the copy/paste menu showing.

This is what I use:

```
function trySelect(el, evenInactive, select_ios) {
    var select = function() {
        try {
            if (mojo.isTouch && select_ios && core.iosDevice && mojo.isInput(el) && document.execCommand) {
                document.execCommand('selectAll');
            } else {
                el.select();
            }
        } catch (e) {
        }
    };
    if (el && el.select && !el.disabled && (!el.readOnly || el.selectReadOnly) && mojo.isInput(el)) {
        if (evenInactive || mojo.activeElement() === el) {
            if (mojo.isTouch && core.webkitVer) {   // http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=32865
                setTimeout(select, 0);
            } else {
                select();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That references some internal functions:

- mojo.isTouch - true for a touch device
- core.iosDevice - true for an iOS device
- mojo.isInput - tests for an input element
- mojo.activeElement() - document.activeElement

edit: `document.execCommand('selectAll');` should not be used and `el.setSelectionRange(0, el.value.length);` used instead. That seems to work fine on iOS5... It might not work on iOS4 (I don't have an iOS4 device to test on).

Answer (score -1):

This one works for me.

```
        $("input[type='text'],select,textarea").focus(function () {
            $(this).addClass('text-focus');
        });

        $("input[type='text'],select,textarea").blur(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('text-focus');
        });

       .text-focus
       {
       border: 1px solid #ea9a00;
       }
```