# jQuery .select() for mobile?

Tags: jquery, mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selecting text on focus using jQuery not working in iPhone iPad Browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924506/selecting-text-on-focus-using-jquery-not-working-in-iphone-ipad-browsers)

jQuery.select() method selects all text in an input field and the user can easily copy/paste.

```
$('#linkModal input').live("click", function(){
  $(this).select();
});
```

easy.

But, this breaks on mobile devices, specifically mobile Safari on iPhone.  Possibly because it is a read-only field, but either way I want the user to select it in order to copy/paste.

Form:

```
<input type="text disabled" readonly="true" value="user needs to copy/past" />
```

Comment: the "focus" instead of "click" event still doesn't work on mobile devices, specifically mobile Safari on iPhone

Comment: What do you mean by "locked"?  Do you mean the disabled attribute?

Comment: No, I meant [the `readonly` attriubte](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.2). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That's what I have.  It works on desktop, not on Mobile Safari