# Select text on focus using jQuery, again

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad, select, focus

Looking for a solution that works for all browsers including on iPad/iPhone.  I have reviewed the past posting for this question, and the one as follows is working all fine, except that it is not working on IE:

```
$("input[type='text'], textarea, input[type='password'], input[type='number']").live('mouseup', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("input[type='text'], textarea, input[type='password'], input[type='number']").live('focus', function() {
    this.setSelectionRange(0, 9999);
});​
```

Comment: Just as a side note, .live is now deprecated, and you should use jQuery .on

Comment: What is the point of trying to prevent the default action of `mouseup`?  And, please describe what you are trying to accomplish with your code.  Just posting code and saying it isn't working doesn't tell us what you're trying to do.

Comment: this is a belated follow up to the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924506/selecting-text-on-focus-using-jquery-not-working-in-iphone-ipad-browsers which should give all background info of this issue.

Comment: I also found out a solution that we need to add an onclick function as follows:   $("input[type=text]").live('click', function() { 
  $(this).select();
  this.setSelectionRange(0, 9999);
  });

Comment: Actually, this above comment from user1045358 was the only solution that worked for me for the iPhone/iPad! Maybe this should be the answer and upvoted...

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked well for me:

```
$("input[type=text]").live('click', function() {
    $(this).select();
    this.setSelectionRange(0, 9999);
});
```

However this while the simplest solution has the downside that it doesn't pre select a text field when navigating with the keyboard. An alternative for this particular issue can be found at: [Looking for a better workaround to Chrome select on focus bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380458/looking-for-a-better-workaround-to-chrome-select-on-focus-bug)

Note: this answer is from comment 4 on the original question.